# Mil tradutores são melhores que um

Tags: novo-recurso, tradução

Durante muito tempo nossa comunidade discutiu as falhas do processo de tradução do SOpt. Estes problemas, que não eram poucos, se acumulavam para produzir um resultado muito abaixo do esperado e muito, muito abaixo do que a comunidade merece. As traduções, até hoje, são irregulares, inconstantes e muitas com qualidade bem baixa.

Esse não é o ideal que queremos para o site e passamos boa parte deste ano discutindo alternativas de melhorar o processo. Um dos principais problemas era o ponto único de falha, já que as traduções todas tinham que passar por uma pessoa. Obviamente isso não é ideal e isso se manifestou ao longo do tempo. A solução óbvia para esse problema (e outros) era encontrar um jeito de fazer uso da disposição e conhecimento da comunidade.

E nós encontramos.

### Transifex

Há algum tempo nós estamos testando o [Transifex](https://www.transifex.com/projects/p/stack-overflow-pt/language/pt_BR/) como plataforma de *crowdsourcing* da tradução do site e hoje, finalmente, podemos deixar vocês contribuirem com o site! A tradução está aberta a todos que quiserem ajudar, sem restrição de reputação, tempo no site ou qualquer outra regra. Quem quiser ajudar será bem-vindo.

A comunidade sempre se mostrou incrivelmente disposta a contribuir com o site e, em diversas ocasiões, a questão da tradução comunitária veio à tona. O Transifex é a melhor opção dentre as que avaliamos para permitir que a comunidade possa participar, mas ainda manter um nível seguro de revisões e controle, já que qualquer iniciativa totalmente aberta tem alguns riscos associados.

A estrutura dos projetos de tradução no Transifex tem algumas características particulares e como a ajuda está toda em Inglês (infelizmente), aqui vai um apanhado geral de como as coisas estão organizadas lá dentro:

#### Projeto Stack Overflow em Português

A página do [**nosso projeto**](https://www.transifex.com/projects/p/stack-overflow-pt/) tem informações básicas sobre a atividade recente e as línguas para as quais ele é traduzido. A lista tem Inglês como idioma original e Português (Brasil)<sup>1</sup> como idioma de tradução.

#### Equipe de tradução

Na [**página do Português (Brasil)**](https://www.transifex.com/projects/p/stack-overflow-pt/language/pt_BR/) você pode clicar no botão "Entrar na equipe" para pedir acesso ao projeto e, à partir daí poder enviar suas traduções. Depois que seu pedido de acesso ao grupo for aceito (não deve demorar muito. Não há nenhuma regra especial para ser aceito) você pode começar a traduzir o conteúdo do site. Basta clicar no botão "Traduzir" na página do projeto.

#### Traduzindo

Existem 3 tipos de strings no Transifex:

- **Revisadas**: Strings que foram traduzidas e revisadas. Essas são as strings que já estão "prontas" e não precisam de atenção imediata. Isso **não** quer dizer que elas não podem - ou não precisam - ser alteradas nunca. O trabalho de tradução é constante e, caso você veja algo que pode ser melhorado, sinta-se à vontade para sugerir mudanças.
- **Não-revisadas**: São strings que tem alguma tradução, mas que ainda não foram avaliadas por um revisor. Qualquer pessoa pode traduzir essas strings para que elas sejam revisadas, após a revisão elas são "bloqueadas" e voltam a não poderem ser traduzidas.
- **Não-traduzidas**: São strings que ainda não tem nenhuma tradução, e qualquer pessoa pode editá-la. Assim que uma tradução é feita, ela passa para a fila de **não-revisadas**.

Qualquer membro do grupo pode traduzir strings **não-revisadas** ou **não-traduzidas**, mas apenas os revisores da equipe<sup>2</sup> podem revisar strings ou traduzir strings revisadas.

#### Fluxo

O Stack Overflow em Japonês foi a cobaia do experimento e eles chegaram a um fluxo que a podemos adotar, mas que absolutamente pode ser melhorado. Ele está detalhado aqui, mas aberto a qualquer tipo de edição:

1. Usuários colocam os bugs de tradução no Meta
2. Alguém adiciona o link para o post do Meta nos comentários das strings relacionadas
3. Um dos revisores marca as strings como **não-revisadas**
4. Alguém sugere uma tradução no Meta, ou diretamente no Transifex
5. Revisores analisam a tradução e determinam se está tudo certo
6. Aproximadamente 1 vez por semana todas as alterações passam pela revisão final e são importadas para o site

O fluxo não é perfeito, principalmente por exigir passos extras (2 a 4, que dependem dos revisores) que impedem que a comunidade possa efetivamente tomar conta da maior parte das traduções. Uma solução possível é ter todas as strings constantemente como **não-revisadas**, mas isso abre o risco de vandalismo. Outra solução é usar o mecanismo de sugestão de traduções do Transifex, mas até agora não sabemos muito bem como ele funciona, ou se ele pode gerar notificações para os revisores, evitando que as sugestões passem despercebidas.

### Comentários

Segundo o Transifex, estamos 83% traduzidos. Não falta muita coisa, mas ainda assim é bastante trabalho. O Transifex apresenta as strings de maneira desconexa e muitas delas são usadas em mais de um lugar de uma vez o que dificulta o trabalho. Por isso acredito que não adianta muito ir para o Transifex procurar coisas pra traduzir. O melhor a fazer é procurar partes do site mal ou não traduzidas e buscá-las no Transifex para realizar a tradução. É a melhor maneira de manter a sanidade e não se perder num mar de palavras soltas.

O Transifex tem algumas ferramentas de categorização que podem ajudar, como as tags e comentários nas strings. Como o SOja vem fazendo, comentários podem ser úteis para associas todas as strings relacionadas a um problema apresentado no Meta. É possível fazer buscas pelos comentários das strings, então procurar pelo `id` de um post no Meta é uma excelente maneira de encontrar tudo que tem a ver com um problema.

Da mesma maneira as tags podem ser usadas para identificar as páginas onde determinada string aparece, ajudando a organizar e facilitando a encontrar problemas. Tudo isso pode ser feito de maneira gradual. Tentar organizar tudo de uma vez é receita para irritação e desgaste.

Esse guia não apresenta **todas** as ferramentas do Transifex, como a busca de concordância, glossário ou uso de comentários para reportar problemas. O Transifex é uma ferramenta nova e é difícil entender tudo que ele pode fazer até que mais pessoas estejam fazendo uso dele.

### Notas

<sup>1.</sup> A língua do nosso projeto é Português (Brasil) mas isso **não significa** que as traduções devam estar todas em PT_BR. A ideia é que elas sejam os mais neutras o possível, que era o que eu vinha tentando fazer enquanto era responsável "exclusivo" pelas traduções. O projeto está em Português (Brasil) por uma escolha errada dos devs quando estavam configurando tudo. Se quiserem, podemos tentar migrar os dados para outra equipe do Transifex - em "Português" apenas - e todo mundo pode pedir acesso de novo.

<sup>2.</sup> Hoje temos 3 revisores: eu, o bfavaretto e o utluiz (nossos moderadores).

Comment: Sempre se esquecem dos portugas :P

Comment: @JorgeB. A gente pode mudar se vocês desejarem ;)

Comment: @Gabe acho que não vale a pena, desde que se mantenha o português neutro como dito na pergunta.

Comment: Nunca participei da tradução do SOpt, mas tem um texto que sempre vejo em inglês, que é aquele que aparece quando você faz uma edição tendo < 2000 de rep, informando que a edição será revisada. Qual seria a melhor maneira de eu achar esse texto no Transifex ou no Meta para propor uma tradução?

Comment: @Molx Se o texto está em Inglês e você tiver disposição de traduzí-lo no Transifex, não acho que seja necessário fazer uso do Meta. Basta procurar o texto lá no Transifex e sugerir uma tradução. Se preferir abrir no Meta, explique o problema de preferência com screenshots.

Comment: Essa ferramenta é um bocado complexa.

Comment: @Patrick Yep, mas depois que acostuma não é tão ruim (é assim que funciona a [Síndrome de Estocolmo](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Síndrome_de_Estocolmo))

Comment: Então a ideia é traduzir logo sem abrir no Meta?

Comment: Algumas frases são complicadas de traduzir porque não tem como saber o contexto que elas estão sendo usadas. **:(**

Comment: @JorgeB. vai depender da situação. Se é algo pequeno que você tem certeza de como consertar, sinta-se à vontade. Mas pra qualquer coisa mais relevante o melhor é, definitivamente, trazer pro Meta.

Comment: @renan Bem vindo ao sofrível mundo das traduções :D! Por isso que o melhor a fazer é ver algo errado no site e ir consertar no Transifex, ao invés de vasculhar o Transifex em busca de coisas pra traduzir.

Comment: @Gabe o renan tem duas contas, está mesmo empenhado :D

Comment: @JorgeB. Sockpuppet de tradução!

Comment: @JorgeB. Eu não sei porque a outra conta está aparecendo lá, eu tive que excluir ela porque bugou e eu não consegui fazer login mais. Se tentar visualizar o perfil, a conta não existe hahahaha.

Comment: Estou com uma dúvida, eu faço sugestão de tradução usando o campo "sugestão" ou uso o campo comentários? A vantagem do comentário é que da para postar o link da página de onde surgiu a dúvida rs

Comment: @Gabe, notei agora que o footer do SOpt não está traduzido (as categorias e os nomes "secundários" tipo stats e cooking) e não está no transifex também. Não foi colocado no source ou é porque o footer é "global" Ou a ideia é deixar assim já que são todos sites em inglês mesmo?

Comment: Pelo que eu vi lá, praticamente tudo já foi traduzido. Faltam as revisões...

Comment: @wryel O "correto" seria sugestão, mas infelizmente o Transifex não gera nenhuma notificação sobre novas sugestões. Então acho que comentários são melhores.

Comment: @Molx O rodapé fica em Inglês mesmo. O máximo que talvez seja possível fazer é traduzir os nomes das categorias ("Technology", "Science", etc). Os nomes dos sites temque permanecer em Inglês.

Comment: @renan Muito do que conta como traduzido ainda precisa de acertos na tradução. Chegar a 0 strings sem tradução é muito bom, mas nem de longe quer dizer que acabou o trabalho :D

Comment: @Gabe eu estava me referindo aos nomes das categorias, descrição entre () e *more* mesmo, traduzir os nomes seria uma péssima ideia já que os sites são em inglês.

Answer (score 9):

## A comunidade está trabalhando bastante!

Quase todas as traduções pendentes já estão feitas. Isso quer dizer que novas strings adicionadas pelos desenvolvedores em breve ficarão mais fáceis de encontrar, a apenas um clique de distância pelo link `UNTRANSLATED` do Transifex.

Parabéns a todos que têm colaborado!

## Muito trabalho pela frente para os moderadores e o CM

Agora a fila de revisar está lotada, então peço a paciência de todos até que as traduções entrem no ar. Revisei recentemente mais de 100 traduções, e isso me tomou mais de uma hora. E o meu trabalho ainda precisa passar por uma última revisão do Gabe.

Mesmo após todo esse trabalho, a demanda por novas traduções, ajustes e revisões continuará existindo. Na minha revisão, aprovei diversas strings que podem estar erradas, pois a tradução correta depende do contexto, e ele nem sempre é claro (aliás, na maioria das vezes ele não é claro).

Assim, peço que continuem checando o Transifex, tentando focar no seguinte:

- Caso identifiquem onde uma string é usada no site, registrem isso nos comentários dela (no lado direito do editor do Transifex, aba "comments"). De preferência incluam um link para a página correspondente do SOpt.
- Tentei começar a usar a [ferramenta de glossário](https://www.transifex.com/projects/p/stack-overflow-pt/glossary/l/pt_BR/) do Transifex para registrar termos que devem ser traduzidos de maneira padronizada. Se vocês tiverem acesso à ferramenta (não sei se é só para moderadores e admins), podem contribuir lá também!

Comment: Todo mundo tem acesso ao glossário, acredito

Comment: E sim, parabéns! A velocidade com que acabamos com as strings sem tradução é sensacional!

Comment: @Gabe mandei requisição para entrar no projeto no Transifex ontem e ainda não fui aceito.

Comment: @williamhk2 eu tô de férias! Vou tentar aceitar todo mundo hoje à noite

Comment: @Gabe sem problemas, beleza!

Comment: @williamhk2 Aceitei todo mundo lá! Bem vindo :D