# Tradução de aviso recompensa nas últimas 24 horas em falta

Tags: bug, tradução

A tradução do aviso de recompensa nas últimas 24 horas está em falta. Na mensagem atual lê-se:

> Your bounty on question "..." is completed. You must award it to an
>   answer within 24 hours.

Sugeria a seguinte tradução

> A sua recompensa na questão "..." está completa. Você deve atribui-la a uma resposta dentro de 24 horas.

Comment: Acho que ficaria melhor algo no sentido de que o tempo expirou

Comment: @Marcelo Bonifazio Talvez. Eu acho que não é adequado porque voce ainda tem uma oportunidade. Mas também acho que a mensagem em Inglês não é a melhor. Seria bom que ela indicasse que é o último aviso. `Você deve atribuir a recompensa da questão "..." em 24 horas. Este é a última notificação`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mesmo a comunidade trabalhando bastante, ainda sim temos muito que melhorar e muito serviço pela frente. Você mesmo pode traduzi-la, basta verificar se essa *string* está no [Transifex](https://www.transifex.com/).

Links úteis:

- [Mil tradutores são melhores que um](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2705/mil-tradutores-s%C3%A3o-melhores-que-um)
- [Como ajudar quem traduz o site?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4764/como-ajudar-quem-traduz-o-site)

Comment: @Gabe [A casa já está em ordem](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/a/4711/13626)?