# "Vezes" não está traduzido após novo visual

Tags: bug, status-pronto, internacionalização

Percebi que após a atualização para a nova barra de navegação, o texto "vezes" não está mais traduzido, tanto aqui no meta como no site principal

Segue exemplo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Você mesmo pode contribuir com as traduções quando encontrar algo em inglês. Pode ler mais sobre o assunto em [mil tradutores são melhores que um](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2705/4808). Fiz a tradução no projeto do Transifex, obrigado **:)**

Comment: @Renan obrigado pela resposta