# Qual é o local adequado para colaborar com a tradução do Stack Overflow?

Tags: suporte, tradução

Atualmente, qual é o local adequado para colaborar com a tradução do Stack Overflow?

A pergunta: [Traduções de páginas e links da "Central de Ajuda"](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5316/tradu%C3%A7%C3%B5es-de-p%C3%A1ginas-e-links-da-central-de-ajuda) é atualmente o local válido e usado para ajudar a traduzir o SO?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

O processo de tradução é colaborativo e online.

É feito pela ferramenta [TRANSIFEX](https://www.transifex.com/), e o link para participar é este:

https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-pt/

Na página do Português (Brasil) você pode clicar no botão "Entrar na equipe" para pedir acesso ao projeto e, à partir daí poder enviar suas traduções. Depois que seu pedido de acesso ao grupo for aceito (não deve demorar muito. Não há nenhuma regra especial para ser aceito) você pode começar a traduzir o conteúdo do site. Basta clicar no botão "Traduzir" na página do projeto.

O parágrafo acima foi tirado deste post, onde você encontrará mais informações:

[Mil tradutores são melhores que um](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2705/70)

Comment: Eu me inscrevi essa semana na equipe do SOpt no Transifex, e, embora ainda não tenha tido muito tempo para estudar a ferramenta, me pareceu que o site entrega frases "soltas" para serem traduzidas, ao invés de entregar uma página inteira para ser traduzida. É isso mesmo?

Comment: @PedroGaspar Mais ou menos isso. Tem que ficar atento com o contexto.

Comment: É que a minha motivação inicial para ter entrado na equipe aconteceu porque eu notei que página da ajuda para tópicos que podem ser perguntados está pela metade na versão em português: [On Topic PT](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [On Topic EN](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), e eu queria traduzir o resto da página, para poder usa-la como referência para perguntas do tipo "faça o meu trabalho de escola para mim", que acontece com certa frequência... Não tem como fazer isso, não é? (traduzir uma página específica da central de ajuda)

Comment: @PedroGaspar esse post pode ajudar neste caso mais específico: [Traduções de páginas e links da “Central de Ajuda”](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5316/70)

Comment: @PedroGaspar talvez compense, no chat da rede, na sala Estouro de Pilha, perguntar para o JNat se ainda pode ser dessa forma. Ele é do Staff da rede, tem acesso a coisas que nós moderadores não temos.