# Motivo extra para fechamento de perguntas fora de escopo

Tags: debate, razões-fechamento, escopo-do-site

## ATENÇÃO! Já está ativo!

Poucas pessoas sabem que cada site da rede Stack Exchange permite escolher alguns motivos para fechamento como fora de escopo personalizados para sua própria necessidade, além do usuário que pode escolher esta opção pode fazer uma personalizada para aquele motivo (por sorte o pessoal não abusa disto).

Nós temos pelo menos um *slot* livre para um motivo geral para o nosso SOpt. Sempre foi guardado porque poderia ser necessário um dia para algo importante, então não era usado. Faz sentido, mas ficaria estranho postergar isto para sempre porque tornaria esta opção como inexistente, já estamos completando 5 anos, temos essa maturidade). <strike>Ao adotarmos um motivo, e ele é o último, fica muito complicado adotar um outro no futuro (eu tenho solução para matar um dos que são usados hoje se for muito necessário). Então p</strike>Precisamos decidir com cautela se vamos adotar este novo motivo e qual seria ele. É fato que este motivo tem sido absurdamente mais prevalente que os outros motivos específicos que temos hoje.

Este ano tivemos um aumento absurdo de fechamentos por um motivo que acredito ser mais específico e ter uma mensagem mais apropriada para ele pode ajudar melhor aos usuários. Este motivo é semelhante ao que já existia na rede no passado que é o "não é uma questão real". Quase sempre são perguntas muito curtas, sem nenhuma informação ou tentativa mínima de mostrar um problema real.

<strike>Uma alternativa para não criar este motivo é *hackearmos* no Transifex a mensagem original do motivo básico de fechamento que é genérico demais e darmos mais informações (não sei se teria espaço suficiente). Se criarmos um novo podemos melhor o texto do motivo primário, e quem sabe até outros motivos (podemos criar essa discussão também), afinal a</strike>A mensagem deve ajudar o máximo possível para o usuário salvar a pergunta dele e se orientar na próxima pergunta, hoje o usuário pode se afastar por não ter a melhor orientação.

Estão postando muitas coisas pedindo:

- ajuda genérica
- uma ideia, luz
- uma dica
- um tutorial completo de forma bem aberta
- oferecendo um trabalho (não sei se seria o caso de diferenciar este caso, mas tem casos que fica em uma linha tênue em puro *off-topic*)
- pedindo para resolver o exercício completamente para ela
- outras coisas parecidas

Ou seja, está fora do que é considerado no escopo e o motivo primário tem servido razoavelmente bem, mas não perfeitamente.

Porém alguns usuários acham estranho porque o assunto é programação, mas a mensagem só fala que não é sobre programação e gera estranheza e não orienta o que a pessoa pode fazer para salvar a sua questão.

Veja bem, a maioria desses casos não haverá salvação, como todo fechamento de fora de escopo, a pessoa não tem um problema real, específico sobre programação, ela só tem um pedido genérico de ajuda, portanto não é uma questão real para um site de Q&A, não está dentro do [nosso escopo definido na central de ajuda](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). É diferente da pergunta não estar clara ou ampla demais que geralmente tem salvação com algum esforço do autor original. Esta só se salva se for outra coisa completamente diferente, o que seria bom que ele o fizesse.

Então precisamos decidir <strike>3</strike>2 coisas:

- <strike>Devemos alterar o motivo primário para especificar melhor o que a pessoa pode fazer neste caso? (não há garantias que dê para fazer e pra mim é plano B)</strike>
- Devemos queimar nosso último motivo personalizado do site para criar este motivo? Caso não, há outro motivo melhor?
- Qual o texto que devemos adotar?

Poste uma resposta ou vote em uma se concordar com o que foi postado. Vou apenas sugerir um texto inicial deste motivo novo (minha preferência), não o trate como um recomendação final, é só para vocês terem uma base para produzir um melhor:

> Apesar do assunto ser programação, esta pergunta não parece atender os critérios de qualidade para um site de Q&A. As perguntas aqui precisam ser para problemas específicos, práticos ou conceituais sobre algoritmos, ferramentas e técnicas de programação e desenvolvimento de software [Veja como melhorar sua pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

O máximo é 400 caracteres. Infelizmente acho que o URL conta junto.

---

Estou esperando dar 30 dias para usarmos o texto mais votado. Parece que não há ninguém contra. Mas se alguém achar que já podemos implementar agora e mudamos depois se precisar, é só se manifestar.

Comment: Acho que há muito espaço para melhoria em todas as atuais mensagens de fechamento. Como já comentei anteriormente com a equipe de moderação, acho ainda que várias delas podem ser "hackeadas" no transifex, mas é delicado, não pode fugir demais da intenção original de cada uma (ou pode? polêmico...)

Comment: @bfavaretto vamos começar discutir isto.

Comment: Como disse [aqui](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7441/precisamos-de-um-motivo-de-fechamento-que-a-pergunta-n%c3%a3o-est%c3%a1-em-portugu%c3%aas#comment28771_7441): os CMs podem alterar o número de razões personalizaveis permitidas para haver espaço para as que foram demonstravelmente necessárias, portanto não precisam de "andar a poupar um _slot_ para aquele dia especial" :P

Comment: @JNat bom saber isto, a informação "oficial" que tínhamos era que não podia criar nada novo. É bom não abusar, mas ficamos mais tranquilos quanto a isto.

Comment: Maniero, em *"Então precisamos decidir 2 coisas"* você riscou o primeiro item, não seria o segundo?

Comment: @PedroGaspar acho que não, podendo criar outros motivos, acho desnecessário mudar o motivo já existente. Deixa ele como tá para *off-topic* total, quando é sobre algo completamente fora. Não?

Comment: @Maniero, acho que podia melhorar o texto, como você propôs, do jeito que está pode causar certa confusão para quem está chegando. E para *off-topic* total já tem o *"Abertamente fora do assunto (essa pergunta não tem nada a ver com programação)"*, né!

Comment: @PedroGaspar mas aí é só mudar o texto ligeiramente, não para incluir uma especificidade, né?

Comment: Sim, acho que seria interessante aproveitar o ensejo para aprimorar o texto dessa opção, ajudaria a ficar mais claro para todos, na minha opinião. Mas volto a insistir que seria muito interessante que aquela página *on-topic* da ajuda seguisse o padrão da versão EN, porque aí sim ficaria mais claro para os novatos (para os que se dão ao trabalho de clicar no link e ler o texto, pelo menos, que são minoria, mas existem!). Eu me comprometo a fazer a tradução se alguém disser que dá para alterar.

Comment: Eu evitaria usar a sigla Q&A que muitos principiantes não devem saber o que significa. Coloque "perguntas e respostas" no lugar.

Answer (score 16):

Eu sugiro assim:

> Apesar de ser sobre programação, esta pergunta não parece atender os critérios mínimos de qualidade e detalhamento para um site de perguntas e respostas. As perguntas aqui precisam ser para problemas específicos, práticos ou conceituais sobre algoritmos, ferramentas e técnicas de programação e desenvolvimento de software. [Melhore a pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Isso daí dá 389 caracteres que codificados em UTF-8 dá 399 bytes.

Observações:

- Eu evitaria usar a sigla *Q&A* que muitos principiantes não devem saber o que significa. Uso "*perguntas e respostas*".
- Ao invés de colocar "*Veja como melhorar sua pergunta*", coloquei "*Melhore a pergunta*". O texto de uma forma imperativa tende a induzir mais o usuário a clicar no link, além de ser um pouco mais curto.
- Acho importante enfatizar "*critérios mínimos de qualidade e detalhamento*".

Comment: Melhor assim ainda que não sei se o imperativo não é melhor, a pessoa já naõ clica sendo, imagina sem ser.

Answer (score 3):

## 1. Devemos alterar o motivo primário para especificar melhor o que a pessoa pode fazer neste caso.

> Porém alguns usuários acham estranho porque o assunto é programação, mas a mensagem só fala que não é sobre programação e gera estranheza e não orienta o que a pessoa pode fazer para salvar a sua questão.

Isso é bem verdade, quando eu era mais novato e me deparei com essa mensagem nas primeiras vezes eu fiquei pensando justamente isso: *"Ué, mas essa pergunta **é** sobre programação, por que será que foi fechada?"*.

Para refrescar a memória, essas são as nossas mensagens hoje:

> Sinalizando > Fechando > Fora de escopo
>
> - Essa pergunta não parece ser **sobre programação**, dentro do escopo definido na [central de ajuda](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).
> - Essa pergunta não pertence ao site porque **não está em Português**. Poderá ser reaberta se for traduzida. ~~ This question is off-topic because it's **not written in Portuguese**. It may be reopened if translated.
> - Esse problema **não pode ser reproduzido**, ou é um **erro de digitação**. Mesmo dentro do escopo do site, sua solução dificilmente seria útil a outros usuários no futuro. Problemas assim podem ser evitados com a criação de um [exemplo Mínimo, Completo e Verificável](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).
> - **Abertamente fora do assunto** (essa pergunta não tem nada a ver com programação)
> - Esta pergunta pertence a outro site da rede Stack Exchange

E essas são as mensagens do SOen:

> Flagging > Closing > Off-Topic
>
> - Questions about **general computing hardware and software** are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming. You may be able to get help on [Super User](https://superuser.com/about).
> - Questions on **professional server- or networking-related infrastructure administration** are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve programming or programming tools. You may be able to get help on [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/about).
> - Questions asking us to **recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource** are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393) and what has been done so far to solve it.
> - Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it *in the question itself*. Questions without *a clear problem statement* are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).
> - This question was caused by **a problem that can no longer be reproduced** or **a simple typographical error**. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting [the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) before posting.
> - **Blatantly off-topic** (this question has nothing to do with programming)
> - This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network

O que mais me incomoda normalmente são mensagens de pedidos pra fazer trabalhos de curso/escola/faculdade. Inclusive outro dia eu estava tentando descobrir uma forma de [traduzir nossa página da ajuda On-Topic](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7404/qual-%C3%A9-o-local-adequado-para-colaborar-com-a-tradu%C3%A7%C3%A3o-do-stack-overflow#comment28671_7405), porque a nossa versão PT só tem metade do texto que a versão EN, e na versão EN há um trecho que fala justamente sobre isso (entre outras coisas adicionais que seria interessante incluir na nossa):

> 3. Questions asking for *homework help* must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it.

Eu acho que a sua sugestão de texto está bem boa!

E não consigo pensar no momento em outra sugestão, a não ser incrementar a página da central da ajuda, caso contrário pode não ser muito esclarecedor para um iniciante, quais foram os motivos exatos do fechamento.

Comment: "Essa pergunta não parece ser **sobre programação**" - para mim, o principal problema é que o trecho "sobre programação" está em negrito, dando a impressão de que a pergunta não é sobre programação. Muitas vezes é, mas não está no escopo porque ainda falta alguma coisa (um [mcve], por exemplo). A mensagem destaca algo que não é o principal problema, então retirar o negrito já seria uma melhoria (talvez o trecho "dentro do escopo..." é que devesse estar em negrito). E se mudar para: "Apesar da pergunta ser sobre programação, não está no escopo do site etc (link pra central)"?

Comment: Eu gosto do "Questions seeking debugging help", talvez possamos usar algo parecido: "Perguntas sobre programação devem ser sobre um problema específico, **devem ter o código que você já fez** e descrever em detalhes o que o programa deveria fazer e o erro que acontece (não diga apenas que *"não funciona"*), com exemplos de entrada e saída e mensagens de erro. Veja como criar um [Exemplo Mínimo, Completo e Verificável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)"

Comment: Mudei um pouco a pergunta dada a luz do Jnat. Foi bom trazer as mensagens do SOen. Se achar que mais algum pode ser útil pode trazer, talvez até em outra pergunta se for sobre outros assuntos. Não acho que devemos reproduzir as mensagens de outros sites, mas pode ajudar ter ideias. Só usaremos o que faz sentido para nós. E para além do que o bfavaretto já falou podemos pensar em "hackear" as mensagens da central da ajuda também, embora elas sirvam para poucos usuários que vão lá ver mesmo, não deixa de ser educacional.

Comment: @hkotsubo uma ideias que eu tinha era mudar o negrito para o outro trecho porque ele é o mais importante, mas com uma mensagem nova fica melhor ainda. E pensei em tentar colocar alguma coisa sobre ter código, mas nessa mensagem não cabe. Até porque aqui somos mais permissivos com questões que não tenham código do que o SOen (na prática lá depende da hora que você posta), desde não seja uma pergunta que só dê para responder com código, mas na maioria parte das vezes esses casos devem ser fechados com "não clara"

Comment: embora tem muitos casos que a pergunta está tão ruim que nem dá para notar que só falta o código :D E se não ficou claro, não estou dizendo para sermos tão específicos quanto o SOen para fechar certas coisas, inclusive porque não temos SUpt ou SFpt. E ainda acho que podemos aceitar pedidos de livros a afins, embora não exatamente como pergunta de usuário (tem que ser gerido pela comunidade), então até faz algum sentido. Isto é outra discussão pra abrir.

Comment: Acho que pode-se abrir discussão para outros motivos específicos (*off-topic*), aqui é sobre ser um pedido genérico. Se acharem que *debug* merece uma separada, podem propor (por enquanto eu acho que não, ainda não podemos abusar, e podemos fazer depois se for muito necessário, por hora prefiro adaptar a mensagem pra deixar isso mais claro).