# Precisamos de um motivo de fechamento que a pergunta não está em português?

Tags: debate, razões-fechamento

## Com o comentário do Jnat acho que este post se torna irrelevante agora

Ou pelo menos ele deveria ter outro foco. Só acho que devemos matá-lo se ele tiver algo nocivo hoje, e não parece ser o caso.

Infelizmente fomos informados equivocadamente que não poderia criar outros se necessário.

Talvez seja o caso de encerrar ou remover isto.

---

Nunca fui um grande fã deste motivo e o tempo foi deixando isto mais sólido.

A maioria das perguntas que são fechadas por este motivo e que não serão mais reabertas costumam ter outros problemas e na verdade é muito melhor usar um desses motivos para fechar porque mesmo que seja traduzido ainda é um problema.

Os casos que são resolvidos fica fechado por pouco tempo. E convenhamos, se alguém respondê-la não nos causa problema real, e é provável que o AR ou mesmo um membro da comunidade queira traduzi-la, se o AP não o fizer.

Tem sido mais ou menos raro este tipo de problema e em quase todos os casos a pessoa traduz quando um usuário informa. Quase sempre antes da pergunta ser fechada ela já está traduzida.

Não digo que precise acabar já com ela, até porque não tem tanta necessidade agora, mas se um dia precisamos de um motivo extra para fechar perguntas poderíamos matá-la. Veja [Motivo extra para fechamento de perguntas fora de escopo](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7440/101).

Se ainda tiver perguntas fechadas com este motivo e não removidas provavelmente compensa remover na mão e se tiver alguma exceção pode-se usar um fechamento personalizado para indicar que este é o motivo (duvido). Matando todas perguntas com este motivo ele pode ser reaproveitado.

O que acham?

- Mata já?
- Mata quando precisar de um motivo novo de fora de escopo?
- O motivo é importante e deve ser preservado pra sempre?

Comment: Geralmente eu comento "traduza a pergunta". Mas se eu vejo que, mesmo após traduzida, ela será off-topic, eu voto para fechar (colocando como não clara, ampla, enfim, o motivo que seria usado se ela já estivesse traduzida) conforme [esta recomendação](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7108/112052). Então acaba sendo um motivo meio inútil...

Comment: O ideal era que o sistema conseguisse agregar motivos de fechamento com multiplos. Assim a pessoa sabia logo que tinha multiplos problemas a tratar

Comment: Só uma pequena nota: se um site nos demonstrar que precisa de mais motivos para fechamento que os personalizáveis por norma (3), nós aumentamos o número de opções permitidas. Que é como quem diz: se este motivo é usado e faz sentido, não é preciso removê-lo só porque achamos que um outro motivo talvez venha a ser mais necessário; os CMs podem alterar o número de razões personalizaveis permitidas para haver espaço para as que foram demonstravelmente necessárias.

Answer (score 9):

### Mata já.

Eu coloco sempre um comentário.

Não havendo esse motivo, permitirá que seja usado outro, caso aplicável.

Answer (score 5):

## Mata quando precisar de um motivo

Comment: O chato vai ser ficar escrevendo o mesmo comentário à mão toda vez que aparecer algo em inglês, então eu evitaria enquanto possível. Mas concordo que seja o motivo mais descartável.

Comment: Já acontece, quase todos casos um usuário escreve um comentário normal. Na prática quase nunca é fechado ou deveria ser fechado por esse motivo.

Comment: Quanto mais o tempo passa, mais perguntas dessas vão ter que tratadas. Acho que tem que sacar fora...

Answer (score 0):

**Mata já.**
(para votar nessa opção, vá na [resposta do ramaral](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/7443/86952))

No começo eu era mais flexível quanto a isso, sempre deixava um comentário dizendo que aqui se pergunta e responde na língua portuguesa e pedia para traduzir, e nunca sinalizava.

Até que um dia no SOen apareceu uma nova pergunta em espanhol, eu deixei comentário dizendo que ali devia ser usado o inglês, mas, traduzi a pergunta, porque não era muito longa. Depois disso fui responde-la, porque eu sabia a resposta, mas nisso já tinha mais uns 3 ou 4 comentários dizendo que ali só podia fazer perguntas em inglês, e antes mesmo que eu começasse a resposta, a pergunta desapareceu da minha tela com um aviso de que ela já tinha sido removida.

Depois desse dia eu passei a ser rígido aqui no SOpt também, já sinalizava logo sem nem ler o que estava escrito, nem deixar comentário.

Mas, pelas mensagens aqui parece que nossa comunidade PT é mais flexível mesmo em relação a essa questão. Sendo assim, creio que devemos demonstrar isso nas opções de fechamento.

Comment: Me desculpem, agora que me toquei que postar uma nova resposta com uma opção que já está sendo votada em outra resposta, só vai atrapalhar a soma dos votos. É que eu queria expor minha experiência e motivos. Melhor apagar a minha resposta e votar na resposta do @ramaral?

Comment: Editei minha resposta e vou votar na resposta do @ramaral.

Comment: De fato, mas não chega atrapalhar muito porque podemos somá-las.

Comment: Acabei de pensar, não podemos somar porque a pessoa pode ter votado nos dois, mas de qq forma é irrelevante agora.