# O que fazer com perguntas do tipo "pode fazer isto ou não?"?

Tags: debate, perguntas-fechadas, qualidade

O pessoal anda criativo em como fazer perguntas complicadas de responder e até fechar.

Tem aparecido perguntas onde a pessoa descreve o problema, quase sempre vagamente, e termina perguntando "tem como fazer isto?". A resposta quase sempre é um sim, embora tenhas casos que é não.

Uma resposta só sim ou não é pouco útil. Explicar porque não para dar alguma utilidade pode ser complicado porque sequer tem informação suficiente, é comum ter que especular. Vai ajudar pouco ou nada outra pessoa, ou até mesmo a pessoa que perguntou, mas de qualquer forma, quase sempre é sim e não tem o que explicar a não ser mostrar para a pessoa como fazer, o que de fato entendo que é isto que a pessoa quer, ela não quer só um sim ou não. Mas não dá para ter certeza.

Qual a melhor abordagem para lidar com isto? Fechar, certo? Como o que? Ampla, não clara, [fora de escopo](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7440/101). Algo mais? Outra coisa?

E se ela só quer "sim ou não" mesmo?

## Edit

Estou destacando porque apesar de ter uma boa resposta ainda não teve participação significativa da comunidade e vejo que algumas pessoas reclamam quando eu faço o que está na resposta postada aqui. Espero mais *feedback* para agir de acordo com a vontade da comunidade.

Comment: Eu fecharia como não clara. Se tem de especular é porque não está clara. Infelizmente vejo muitas respostas especulativas. O problema é que uma pessoa perde o seu tempo a tentar perceber o que o AP quer e deixa um comentário. Mas entretanto vem alguém que responde na especulação, até acerta e o AP marca como certo. E uma pessoa andou a perder tempo para nada. Cada vez que eu tento voltar a responder no site acontece-me isso. Desmotiva-me logo.

Comment: A preocupação em manter a qualidade é essencial e ao mesmo tempo parece controversa(só parece). Isso porque a comunidade tem níveis diferentes: pessoas querendo ajudar. Esses com conhecimento já amplo na área, conhece metodologias, padrões, etc  e pessoas querendo respostas, iniciantes, aventureiros, intermediários.

Comment: Não sei se sou aventureiro ou alguém entre amador-intermediário, pois comecei a desenvolver um website para mim e com isso comecei a aprender lógica e programação, hoje sei o suficiente e mais um pouco, mas muitos termos técnicos utilizados por vocês programadores, eu sinceramente desconheço, aprendi MVC, Abstração, Condição de Corrida, Sintaxe, e um pouco mais graças a vocês, e muitas perguntas que faço, não são tão cruas como os exemplos assim, mas não sei me expressar o suficiente para a compreensão de todos, e não sou vítima, mas sou bem incompreendido muitas vezes, mas SOpt sempre ajudou.

Answer (score 12):

> E se ela só quer "sim ou não" mesmo?

Não vejo utilidade numa pergunta assim para a comunidade. Responderia o autor, mas provavelmente todos os outros usuários que acessariam a pergunta se perguntaria "*ok, sim, mas como faço isso?*". Se ajuda somente o autor, não tem porque ter espaço no site. Um comentário com o "sim/não" e fechando como fora do escopo seriam suficientes (comentário ainda é opcional caso não queira deixar o autor sem resposta).

Mas e se o "como" for algo interessante, posso adicionar na resposta?

Provavelmente sim, mas talvez não nessa pergunta. Se a pergunta foi feita de forma que a resposta seja apenas sim ou não, não há porque responder mais que isso. Muitas vezes fica até confuso. As opções nesse caso seriam editar a pergunta e deixá-la na forma que uma resposta completa poderia ser dada, ou criada outra pergunta de forma apropriada. Obviamente que ambas as opções são válidas quando partindo da suposição que a pergunta foi clara.

> Qual a melhor abordagem para lidar com isto? Fechar, certo? Como o que? Ampla, não clara, fora de escopo. Algo mais? Outra coisa?

Se foi perguntado vagamente, eu costumo votar como não clara. Uma resposta clara somente é possível quando o autor da pergunta define claramente a origem (o problema) e o destino (resultado esperado). A resposta é o caminho entre origem e destino. Sem um deles suficientemente claro, a chance de se perder ou errar o caminho é grande.

É comum o autor descrever apenas a origem, então sempre é interessante solicitá-lo quanto suas expectativas em relação ao destino. Eu costumo questioná-lo, nesses casos, sobre o que ele espera com a resposta, sobre parâmetros que ele avaliará para definir que uma resposta é útil ou não. Com isso dá, inclusive, para ajudá-lo a definir o destino que ele deseja alcançar.

O fechamento "amplo demais" eu acho muito sensível e, particularmente, não gosto muito dele. Para saber que é amplo, a pergunta precisa estar 100% clara e quem está votando ter conhecimento do processo que leva da origem ao destino. E vejo que a fronteira que diferencia uma resposta grande de uma resposta para algo amplo é bastante nebulosa e depende muito de cada um.

Muitas vezes vejo votos como "amplo demais" apenas porque a pergunta demandava uma resposta longa e o votante aparentemente estava com preguiça de fazê-la (provavelmente eu já fiz isso alguma vez).

Comment: pode ser que eu esteja tendo uma visão limitada por conhecer pouco do funcionamento do SOpt, mas eu gostei da idéia "... As opções nesse caso seriam editar a pergunta e deixá-la na forma que uma resposta completa poderia ser dada, ou criada outra pergunta de forma apropriada."

Answer (score 1):

Vou chamar essas perguntas de booleanas, pois a resposta delas é simplesmente "sim" ou "não".

> Qual a melhor abordagem para lidar com isto? Fechar, certo?

Sim, certo.

> Como o que?

Vamos por eliminação.

1. *Ampla*: Não, muito pelo contrário, a pergunta é bem específica.
2. *Não clara*: Talvez não seja clara, mas isso não tem a ver com ser booleana.
3. *Baseada em opiniões*: Idem o que escrevi acima.
4. *Fora do escopo*: Agora sim! O stackoverflow claramente não foi feito para perguntas booleanas. O problema de usar este motivo é que essas perguntas não são explicitamente proibidas pela [central de ajuda](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask).

A minha sugestão é: Vamos incluir na central de ajuda que perguntas booleanas não são bem vindas, e a partir daí poderemos fechá-las por serem fora do escopo.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, não sei se você considerou que quase sempre o que a pessoa quer não é o sim ou não, ela quer um sim e quer que façam para ela. Daí a dúvida, então considerando isto a resposta permanece a mesma?

Comment: @Maniero Estou ciente disso. Eu entendo que a pessoa é culpada por não se expressar corretamente, por isso sugeri atualizar a central de ajuda, assim temos um motivo "oficial" pra fechar este tipo de pergunta sem ter que dar explicações mirabolantes pro OP (ele que leia a central de ajuda e entenda o porquê do fechamento). Senão, o OP pode vir chorar aqui no meta argumentando que não tá escrito em nenhum lugar que este tipo de pergunta não é bem vinda.