# Lei de Cunningham e o Stack Overflow

Tags: debate

Há algum tempo venho pensando sobre o assunto, mas acho válido expor a discussão aqui no Meta.

Muito se discute do problema e alternativas para o Stack Overflow não virar um fórum de suporte técnico, fugindo da sua filosofia central para atender ao assistencialismo. Nesse contexto, já percebi que, no geral, as perguntas que possuem apenas uma pergunta (sem descrever alguma tentativa, sem exemplos de código, etc) são mal recebidas pela comunidade - excetuando-se as perguntas teóricas na maioria das vezes. Se o usuário abre uma pergunta no site com "como funciona..." ou "como faz..." ela provavelmente será fechada como fora do escopo ou ampla demais, seguida (ou precedida) de uma chuva de comentários do tipo "o que você tentou?". Se ele edita (ou já cria a pergunta) com algum trecho de código, **seja ele qual for**, a comunidade tende a aceitar melhor. Muitas vezes, o que acontece é o autor publicar um trecho de código absurdo, com a sintaxe completamente errada, mas mesmo assim a comunidade tende a aceitar melhor em relação a quando nenhum código é apresentado.

> Exemplo disso é o que levou a ser criada a pergunta [O que acontece com as filas de análise?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7606/5878)

Por um lado, se o autor não publica um trecho de código fica parecendo que a pergunta é uma "façam para mim"; por outro lado, se o autor publica um trecho de código, por mais absurdo que esteja, a comunidade tende a aceitar.

Exigir do autor da pergunta alguma tentativa não é, de alguma forma, *incentivar* o assistencialismo? Pois parece que a resposta da comunidade nesses casos é "não iremos discutir as possíveis soluções, só queremos corrigir o seu código". Isso parece ser exatamente o oposto do objeto central do Stack Overflow, não?

De certa forma, vejo que esse comportamento acaba incentivando o autor a publicar qualquer trecho de código, por mais absurdo que esteja, do que publicar nenhum. Algo muito errado é melhor que nada.

A **lei de Cunningham** diz exatamente isso:

> A melhor maneira de obter a resposta certa na Internet não é fazer uma pergunta, é postar a resposta errada.

Isso parece se encaixar muito bem em muitos casos no Stack Overflow, mais do que deveria, talvez.

[image: Publicação no XKCD, duty calls]

<sup>[XKCD: Duty Calls](https://xkcd.com/386/)</sup>

O que vocês acham disso? A lei de Cunningham é aplicada no Stack Overflow e seu uso (ou não) traz benefícios ou malefícios à comunidade?

Comment: O problema é que, ao menos na grande maioria dos casos que vejo diariamente aqui, a pergunta sem o código não é clara o suficiente para obter uma resposta, o que faz com que o autor fique solicitando um monte de coisas ou reclamando de um monte de erros gerado pela solução ou até mesmo diga que aquilo não é o que ele esperava, quando alguém responde. Falta é boa vontade de quem pergunta em se esforçar mais pra elaborar algo, no minimo, compreensível. As vezes é mais facil enxergar o problema no código do que o autor explicando, muitas vezes sem se preocupar com ortografia ou gramática[+]

Comment: [+] fazendo com que a gente não só tenha que entender seu problema com a lógica, mas também tenha um esforço enorme em decifrar um texto/comentário mal redigido.

Comment: Por isso raramente reabro uma pergunta fechada nessas condições. Eu vejo a comunidade fazendo as coisas muito no automático (mais ou menos como programam). As pessoas ligam um sinal verde ou vermelho baseado em algum gatilho muito específico, ela não analisa o conteúdo de fato (mais ou menos como programam). Eu tenho tentado evitar em entrar com conflitos com a comunidade e mesmo vendo alguns erros tenho deixado passar, até porque já tem um histórico grande de erros crassos da comunidade virar um enorme problema com algumas pessoas da comunidade quando eu desfiz o que a comunidade havia feito.

Comment: Eu ainda fecho muita coisa logo, porque a comunidade falha muito nisso, mas evito os casos que não tenho tanta certeza, ou adoto um motivo errado para não ir contra a maré. Eu acho o assistencialismo o que mais prejudica o site no momento atual. E é um momento bem delicado. Pra falar a verdade tanto, que todo dia penso em jogar a toalha e deixar a correnteza levar, tamanho é o problema. Sempre disse sobre https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/44/101. Agora o normal é este tipo de pergunta.

Comment: O capricho está cada vez pior, a vontade verdadeira de ter uma resposta está cada vez mais baixo, a pessoa nem quer tentar, nem quer discutir, nem quer reclamar mais. Eu só não sei como resolver isto, o padrão passou a ser algo muito ruim e que dará muito trabalho para colocar em estado aceitável. E estamos tendo bem mais ruído com isso do que algo bom. E note que mesmo eu reclamando de tudo isso eu tento responder muitas coisas ruins. Tento ser mais leve na moderação, mas a comunidade falha muito.

Comment: Não estou reclamando, só observando, eu entendo que todos cansaram, acho normal, até para fechar dá trabalho demais

Comment: Sobre discutir as possíveis soluções, não sei se foi uma forma de dizer, mas discutir não é nosso objetivo, ainda que se o problema for conceitual isso acaba acontecendo, é o normal. Eu mesmo sempre coloco em discussão certas práticas. Eu acho que isso acaba sendo útil para quem quer aprender, que eu ainda acho ser nosso principal objetivo. A discussão caberia em um fórum. O que temos aqui nem é um fórum, é um mural. Sabe, aquele lugar onde as pessoas postam alguma coisa que é do interesse delas esperando que algumas pessoas vejam e atendam seu interesse.

Comment: Pode ter nele coisas bem legais para quem verá o mural, ela pode querer e poder ajudar em algo, mas também pode ter os maiores absurdos. Ou seja, é um Y!R. Eu gostaria de voltar a ter um Q&A. Tenho notado essa questão da pessoa usar o "jeitinho" de colocar um código qualquer só para a pergunta não ser fechada, e funciona. A comunidade compra isso e me engana direitinho. Eu analiso muitas postagens, não posso ficar 10 minutos em cada uma se eu não for responder. Em boa parte dos casos eu decido que a pergunta não é boma em segundos e fecho.

Comment: Se eu perceber que preciso de minutos para decidir se deve fechar eu deixo aberta e espero que outra pessoa analise melhor. Eu não tenho como fazer melhor que isso, já dou muito do meu tempo. Gasto mais tempo e em assuntos que domino mais e me interesso. Me chateia muito quando algo é um tema legal, mas não dá para responder.                 Depois penso se vale uma resposta minha, mas em resumo, eu considero isso um problema. Mas tenho me questionado se não é melhor deixar pra lá.

Comment: Eu tenho feito muito essa pergunta para outras pessoas pra me ajudar decidir, mas ninguém responde :) É mais ou menos binário, ou somos rígidos e realmente aplicamos as regras de um Q&A ou nos transformamos em um mural, para o bem ou para o mal, o público quer o mural. Lembrando que as pessoas (generalizando, claro) que mais contribuíam com coisas legais, que serviam a um grande público, já foram embora definitivamente ou raramente aparecem. O risco que a gente falava há 5 anos não é mais uma hipótese futura, é realidade presente.

Comment: O problema dos alertas que a gente fazia é que achávamos que conseguíamos impedir isto acontecer. Claro ainda estou aqui fazendo o meu melhor, se não é mai ou melhor, é porque não consigo. O dia que eu ver que não dá mais não estarei mais aqui.                           Pra mim colocar o código e a pessoa nem saber o que está acontecendo, não ver um erro, não conseguir interpretar a mensagem de erro, ter ideia do que está acontecendo, ela não entende o mínimo e está fazendo uma pergunta complexa.

Comment: Eu sou leniente com isso, mas por mim se não tem um MCVE claro e "perfeito" nenhuma pergunta deveria ser respondida. Digo mais, não que solucionaria tudo, mas tirar o "entusiastas" da descrição ajudaria. Pelo menos teria um argumento claro para negar certas perguntas. Como eu sempre digo, nada contra o novato, o problema é quem quer ser novato a vida toda. Conheço novato com mais de 30 anos de experiência e experiente com menos de 30 semanas. Considero um farde ter que lidar com pessoas que não querem nunca se profissionalizar. É desanimador.

Comment: O que me anima é ter um novato com tesão pela coisa, que sabe perto de zero, mas está ali de corpo e alma. Desanima ter que lidar com o cara que não sabe português, matemática, um **mínimo** de ciência, pula etapas e tenta fazer algo complexo, e não quer mudar sua atitude, e acha que é obrigação dos outros atender suas demandas. Quero ver a decisão do pessoal para me orientar em como proceder, mas minha opinião é essa. Conteúdo ruim que exija as pessoas terem que praticamente dar uma consultoria pra pessoa não é legal nunca, mesmo que ela tenha disfarçado bem e pareça que ela se esforçou.

Comment: Relacionado: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7464/101 e https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7462/101 e https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7165/101

Comment: Acho o ponto bem interessante, uma coisa que as vezes percebo em perguntas dentro desse senário é que o AP tem simplesmente "vergonha" de postar o código, por achar que está muito ruim, ou por medo de mostrar o total desconhecimento do que está fazendo. É aquele aluno que deixa de perguntar quando o professor pergunta se alguém ficou com alguma dúvida, ai por medo de passar vergonha por algum motivo acaba deixando de perguntar. Talvez aqui a pessoa pergunte, mas acaba deixando de colocar o código. Outras vezes as pessoas nem sabe como colocar o código, vejo muito isso em perguntas de WordPress

Comment: A pessoa simplesmente fala "mas eu não acho o HTML da página" e coloca o link do Wordpress. Muitas vezes essas perguntas são fechadas antes de alguém conseguir comentar alguma coisa. Algumas vezes já falei pra pessoa que o código dela estava tão mal construído que o melhor seria começar novamente do zero. E realmente "salgar carne podre" tentando arrumar um código desse tipo da mais trabalho que se o sujeito não tivesse colocado código algum.

Comment: "*as perguntas que possuem apenas uma pergunta*" - não ficou muito claro isso. Tive que ler umas três vezes e pensar um pouquinho para entender o que você quis dizer com isso.

Comment: @Maniero este [seu comentario](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7507/lei-de-cunningham-e-o-stack-overflow#comment29018_7507) resume e explica perfeitamente o que tentei dizer e provavelmente não consegui no meu, é justamente isso que acaba deixando muitos cansados. Tem muitos novatos que fazem perguntas boas, as vezes não "perfeitas", mas percebe-se um esforço notável ao menos em tentar explicar o problema. O duro é ver pessoas que querem fazer coisas ou mexer com conceitos que nem entendem, e se a gente explica o conceito, a pessoa ignora pois quer algo mastigado, não explicado.

Comment: @hugocsl veja a imagem final desta: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/7509/101 Você tem toda razão, mas a pessoa tem que resolver isso, a não ser que tenha alguma ideia do que possa ser feito aqui, seja na questão da pessoa ter vergonha, seja na questão da pessoa não ter conhecimento mínimo até de usar um site simples (que seria um problema maior se o público fosse cozinheiros, mas não para "programadores"). Só lembrando que comentários podem ser feitos com a pergunta fechada, e quando ela arruma costuma ser reaberta...

Comment: ... As vezes é reaberta sem consertar (ontem aconteceu mais de um caso e talvez por isso o Anderson postou isso aqui). Agora @VictorStafusa acho que ele quer dizer isso "em cada postagem que consideramos ser uma questão (e não uma resposta), tem apenas uma interrogação do que ele ele quer, ele faz uma pergunta no sentido gramatical, mas não tem uma pergunta no sentido conceitual do SOpt, de ser algo com uma dúvida completa, com detalhes, é só a pergunta crua do tipo "e aí, o que eu faço", e não um "eu uso isso, fiz isso, testei assim, deu esse erro, em tal lugar, tentei resolver assim , etc.".

Comment: @Maniero Ele já editou para ficar mais claro.

Comment: Olha, acho que parte do problema é quando o usuário que vem aqui é inocente demais sequer para entender as orientações que lhe são dadas de como fazer uma pergunta. Ou então quando o usuário é alguém fazendo uma pergunta sobre um assunto do qual não tem a menor condição de entender, mais ou menos como uma criança de 4 anos perguntando algo que remete a física nuclear.

Comment: @VictorStafusa bem resumido. E a ferramenta não ajuda muito, não leva a pessoa a construir um resultado. Mas tem mais um detalhe, como uma criança *milennial* de 4 anos, se não está tão à mão, ela não se esforça para obter o que quer, espera que caia no colo.

Comment: A minha perspetiva é cada vez mais individualização. Parece-me impossivel aplicar uma decisão para 100% das perguntas com um critério que não está sujeito a interpretação nem decisão dos usuários, quer sejam eles perguntadores ou respondedores. Em vez de fazer generalizções que não são óbvias, que Tal fazer um estudo das perguntas que se está a referir e tentar implementar Uma medida e acompanhar os resultados? Assim há menos subjetividade

Comment: Na minha opinião - "não iremos discutir as possíveis soluções, só queremos corrigir o seu código" - Acontece devido à sede de ganhar reputação sendo aceita como resposta o código pronto, por isso eu sempre prefiro as perguntas teóricas. Neste quesito acho que os pontos de reputação não incentivam quem realmente quer passar algum conhecimento adiante.

Comment: Não li todos os comentários, mas li a pergunta toda :D... mas acho que só postar um código qualquer não quer dizer nada. Muitas vezes o código postado demonstra que o autor da pergunta quer DE FATO um outro código pronto, ou seja, muitos usuários já "cairam" nessa de que se não mostrar código a pergunta será fatalmente fechada, e na malandragem postam um código nada a ver. Por isso o código postado na pergunta deve ser avaliado e verificado se não é apenas um "enche linguiça".

Comment: Não tinha visto esta pergunta. Mas esse foi precisamente o motivo de eu deixar de participar tão ativamente no site. Porque, quando a pergunta ainda está ali no limbo uma pessoa tenta fechar e depois ajudar a tentar clarificar a ver se dá para reabrir. Entretanto ela ainda nem foi fechada e já está cheia de respostas tão boas como a própria pergunta, uma vez que, a resposta vem do achismo do que o AR acha que o AP quer saber. Assim não dá vontade de tentar ajudar a clarificar a pergunta e depois quiçá responder. Esse é um problema antigo sem solução à vista.

Comment: @Maniero esta bem que merecia destaque ;)

Comment: @JorgeB. acho que passou o momento

Comment: @Maniero pelo contrário este assunto está na ordem do dia do site. Foi colocado em cima da mesa numa altura mais morta do site, o Natal. É na solução deste problema que a comunidade se deveria focar. Muita gente deixou de participar ativamente por causa disso mesmo.

Comment: Eu acho que devemos "abusar" dos comentários, eu tenho muito interesse em aprender como o site funciona, a minha intenção é que o site permaneça sempre saudável, afinal de contas ele já me ajudou tanto, e por isso eu entendo o qual importante são as suas regras , procuro ao máximo aprender com as pessoas que estão aqui a mais tempo, eu mesmo sou um dos caras que "quero um código para responder", mas não era assim no começo, aprendi isso com a comunidade, e antes de melhorar preciso ...

Comment: ... saber onde e como melhorar, já aprendi alguns padrões da comunidade, já fiz perguntas voltadas a pontuação, ao meu ver aquela pergunta não era interessante, mas sabia que a comunidade teria sede para responder, e a fiz, e realmente a galera veio e a valorizou, recebi uma ótima pontuação, mas era algo que com 5 minutos qualquer um encontraria no google, mas por outro lado eu já fiz algumas perguntas, que demorei para elaborar, fiz testes e mais testes antes de postar, e queria de verdade uma boa resposta, me esforcei de verdade para fazer, ...

Comment: ...porem fui negativado e realmente até hoje eu não sei o porque, acho que devemos comentar ao máximo, até mesmo para entender o porque e ter um direcionamento.

Comment: Outro problema é que nem todos acessam a central de ajuda, o que dificulta e muito no começo, a pessoa acha que esta fazendo o certo, outro problema é a interpretação, por exemplo, quando eu li sobre como responder uma pergunta, eu li o seguinte trecho "Qualquer resposta que leve o interessado na direção correta é útil", o que eu entendi, se responder algo, que não seja de fato a resposta, mas que ajude a pessoa eu posso postar como resposta, porem convivendo com a comunidade eu vi que não era bem assim, o...

Comment: ...
 certo é direcionar a pessoa e ajudar pelos comentário, e somente responder se você tiver certeza que aquela é a resposta, quando li este trecho eu achei que algo como "tente isso" seria uma resposta valida, mas na pratica não é, aprendi que o local correto para o "tente isso" seria nos comentários, ou seja, a minha visão diante da central de ajuda foi diferente da realidade.

Comment: E um terceiro problema, mas este eu acho muito complexo, eu tenho mania de fazer "propaganda" do stack, influencio os meus amigos a usarem, ensino como funciona e tudo mais, e sempre me deparo com um ou outro relatando que foram mal recebidos, entendo e já me acostumei com comentários "secos", muitas vezes quando eles me relatam o acontecido com detalhes eu penso, "tá, mas o que há de errado com este comentário?", mas para pessoas que estão de fora um comentário muito seco pode distância os novos usuários.

Comment: Eu acho que esta pergunta é um bom exemplo, https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/359073/dificuldade-com-mascaras-php, é uma pergunta simples de responder e esta clara(ao meu ver), e também é um exemplo que colocaria, "poste o seu código", diante desta discussão eu alteraria somente a tag, e responderia normalmente, acredito que um exemplo é a melhor forma para demonstrar o que realmente queremos dizer, e vocês, o que acham desta pergunta?

Comment: Veja que já temos o seguinte comentário "
Tom, elabore mais a pergunta ela está muito vaga, corre o risco de se fechada.", o que o autor quer é uma simples mascara, será que precisamos de mais informações para isso? Como disse anteriormente, aprendi com a comunidade, que em casos como estes deveria comentar algo como "poste seu código", mas queria saber como lidar em situações como esta.