# Tratamento diferente para perguntas parecidas

Tags: debate

Corro o risco de ser indelicado ou injusto, mas tenho notado que quando pessoas com score baixo fazem perguntas relacionadas a programação e as suas dificuldades diárias, e não colocam códigos porque não cabem, tem as suas perguntas execradas, mas quando outras pessoas com score alto fazem exatamente as mesmas perguntas, aquelas que tangenciam de leve a programação as vezes quase assuntos etéreos (ironia), pelo fato de ter um score alto tem as suas perguntas valorizadas. Acho que estamos tratando questões parecidas com pesos e medidas diferentes em função, não da pergunta, mas do score de quem perguntou.

Essa percepção é antiga e não tenho todas as questões que me deram essa impressão. Tenho apenas as ultimas duas:

Score baixo:

[Conexão via BDE aplicação .NET](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/352359/cone%C3%A7%C3%A3o-via-bde-aplica%C3%A7%C3%A3o-net?noredirect=1#comment706954_352359)

Score alto:

[O que são falsos-positivos em programação?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/351665/o-que-s%C3%A3o-falsos-positivos-em-programa%C3%A7%C3%A3o)

Comment: Consegue listar as semelhanças entre as perguntas citadas? Não sei se consegui identificá-las como você identificou e isso pode influenciar meu julgamento.

Comment: Analisando o conjunto, me parece que o problema está apenas na percepção mesmo. Sugeriria ignorar o score dos usuários envolvidos, que fica mais fácil entender a razão entre a votação e o conteúdo dos posts. Ao menos, no exemplo fornecido, é irrelevante o score do usuário.

Comment: Essas semelhanças tem a ver com percepção. Se você não consegue ver que a primeira é uma questão relacionada a programação ou problema relacionado a TI e a segunda quase nem isso, então eu não sou capaz de mostrar isso.

Comment: E desde quando ser de programação e relacionada a TI é suficiente para estar no [escopo do site](/help/on-topic)? Precisa muito mais que isso. O SOpt não é um site de suporte técnico, é um repositório de conhecimento abrangente. Eventualmente pode dar suporte se o problema apresentado se encaixar em uma série de fatores (e qualidade). Sequer dá pra saber a razão da pessoa não conseguir fazer o que deseja pelo que foi postado. A qualquer momento a pergunta pode ser editada e complementada. A [help] é um bom ponto de partida para entender melhor o funcionamento do site, e o próprio site meta.

Comment: Mas a questão que você levantou é que duas perguntas supostamente semelhantes tiveram tratamentos diferentes. Essas semelhanças não devem ser apenas "perceptivas", senão será apenas a sua opinião. Você precisa, de forma clara, demonstrar porque elas seriam semelhantes e receber o mesmo tratamento. Eu vejo uma pergunta que é bastante vaga, sem detalhes algum, que não define onde quer chegar, contra uma pergunta que foi clara, deu exemplos e definiu exatamente qual era a pergunta a ser respondida. A primeira é uma dúvida técnica que não possui as informações necessárias. A segunda é [...]

Comment: [...] uma pergunta teórica que apresenta todas as informações necessárias. Uma define as linguagens envolvidas (até de forma estranha, mas talvez seja apenas ignorância minha), enquanto a outra é agnóstica às linguagens. Basicamente, o que eu consegui concluir é que as perguntas são completamente diferentes entre si - e eu nem cheguei a analisar a reputação dos autores. Por isso perguntei se você poderia listar essas semelhanças que cita na pergunta. Se é apenas uma "percepção" sua, acho que não há muito o que discutir.

Comment: Acho que um dos maiores erros da comunidade aqui é confundir "pessoas" com "conteúdo". Já vi muito conteúdo de usuários novos sem score recebendo muitos votos. Por que? Porque o conteúdo que ele postou tinha muita qualidade. Ou seja, aqui não estamos _julgando_ pessoas, mas o conteúdo que elas postam.

Answer (score 12):

Para postar algo aqui reclamando de tratamento diferente para perguntas semelhantes deveria mostrar a semelhança. No comentário lá é usado inclusive a expressão "fazem exatamente as mesmas perguntas", como é possível ser exatamente as mesmas perguntas? Tem algum caso para mostrar de exatamente a mesma pergunta que recebeu tratamento diferente? Se isto ocorreu precisamos fechá-la como duplicata.

Elas são completamente diferentes. Uma é conceitual, que é claramente sobre programação, apesar de resvalar em algo mais amplo, e outra é o que a gente chama informalmente de "faça para mim o código que eu preciso agora". Uma só quer saber sobre o que é um termo, a outra tem praticamente zero informações sobre o problema, existe apenas uma muito breve indicação do **tema** do problema.

Não há qualquer indicação da situação específica, na verdade a pergunta é extremamente confusa, mistura coisas que provavelmente só a AP sabe porque estão juntas ali e é bastante incompleta. Mas tudo isso só a tornaria não clara. Em parte ela é ampla porque não tem um problema específico ali, ela quer tudo. Mas acaba sendo também fora de escopo porque é um pedido de ajuda e não uma pergunta, não é uma dúvida específica, não é algo que possa ser resolvido com uma resposta simples, precisaria muito esforço para obter o que é necessário para responder, o que nos tornaria um mural e não um site de Q&A.

As pessoas experientes sabem como fazer perguntas, sabem o que pode ou não, por isso é raro elas terem suas perguntas fechadas. Eu mesmo tive algumas fechadas e até removidas. Claro, é raro, e mais raro hoje do que no passado. Tudo é experiência. E falo de experiência no site e de programação, ou de comunicação.

Se vai afirmar que as pessoas estão tomando decisões baseadas na pontuação, precisa mostrar evidências disso. Existe uma correlação bastante próxima entre pontuação alta e experiência no site ou programação, ou quem sabe até de vida e como manter comunicação clara com outras pessoas. Daí as pessoas estarem decidindo o que fechar por causa da pontuação vai uma grande distância.

Se admite ser apenas percepção não sei se é o caso de afirmar, ainda mais quando posteriormente diz que não é capaz de mostrar as semelhanças, então isto seria considerado apenas um *rant*.

Ninguém disse que a primeira não é de TI, ela só não está no nosso escopo, por sinal esse texto foi criado para deixar bastante claro que é sobre programação, mas não atende aos critérios para considerarmos ela como uma pergunta que pode ser respondida. Vou trazer o texto dela para cá para ler novamente e ver se consegue interpretá-la agora na forma como eu estou lhe informando (ênfase no que contrapõe o que foi argumentado):

> **Apesar de ser sobre programação**, esta pergunta não parece atender os critérios mínimos de qualidade e detalhamento para um **site de perguntas e respostas**. As perguntas aqui precisam ser para **problemas específicos**, práticos **ou conceituais** sobre algoritmos, ferramentas e técnicas de programação e desenvolvimento de software

Aí seria legal ler sobre [o que aceitamos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). E [como fazer melhores perguntas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Alias cada um aproveita a experiência de formas diferentes. Todos tiveram experiências ruins na vida, em sites, inclusive aqui, e eu mesmo sou um que passou por dificuldade no início de uso do Stack Overflow. Aí fui vendo o que eu errei, como as pessoas acertavam e como eu deveria mudar para minha participação ser mais produtiva. E aí as coisas começaram funcionar pra mim, e passou ter uma série de consequências positivas pra minha vida (nem imagina quanto). Algumas pessoas tomam essas experiências negativamente, entram na zona de conforto e preferem desistir, reclamar e manter as mesmas atitudes, e uma série de consequências negativas começam acontecer pra ela, mesmo que ela nem perceba. E geralmente isso vai se avolumando e ela não pode aceitar ser o problema, e começa sempre colocar a culpa nas outras pessoas. Mesmo que as outras pessoas tenham culpa, você não consegue mudar o mundo.

[image: Seja a mudança que você quer ver no mundo]

Vou colocar aqui um slide de uma palestra minha:

[image: O problema é as pessoas não quererem acertar]

Para contextualizar, o Tony Hoare é responsável pelo maior erro da computação, mas também um dos que mais contribuíram para nossa área de conhecimento.

Enfim, aguardamos a pessoa que postou conseguir transformar aquilo em uma pergunta respondível para reabri-la. Se quiser pode ajudar no que for possível. Tomara não ser esse o caso, mas minha experiência é que quando começa assim a chance maior é que a pessoa não consiga reverter a situação, e por se tratar de um caso individual não farei uma análise do porquê isso ocorre.

Pra finalizar o SOpt pode ajudar as pessoas melhorarem em pontos que vão muito além da programação, cada um escolhe seu caminho. Espero ter contribuído para seu futuro sucesso.