# O que acontece com as filas de análise?

Tags: debate, filas-de-análise

Nós sempre tivemos problemas nas filas de análise. As pessoas votam sem analisar. Mesmo com auditoria não adianta muito, a pessoa faz isso. Eu imagino que é para ganhar medalha. Mas pode ser outro motivo. A pessoa pode ter a melhor das intenções de ajudar, mas não sabe bem o que fazer.

Em geral são sempre as mesmas pessoas que erram muito na análise. Claro que, em alguns casos dá para discutir quem está certo, mas há casos bem fáceis. Em geral há discussões no chat (oficial ou não) sobre isso. O problema costuma acabar quando a pessoa ganha a medalha, mas sempre tem gente nova querendo medalha.

Tem casos que ficam bem esquisitos, por exemplo:

[image: Quem fechou e quem reabriu]

A pessoa vota para reabrir e depois vota para fechar sem nenhuma mudança que fez a pergunta ficar pior. Pra mim claramente é um caso da pessoa não saber analisar, seja porque ela não entende o que está acontecendo ali ou porque nem lê nada e vota só pra fazer número para a medalha. Este não é o único caso assim, só o mais recente.

Tem muito caso que a pessoa vota para reabrir só porque alguém editou algo, ou colocou um código aleatório qualquer. A fila de análise é para analisar, não para dar voto automático. Tem que ver se a pergunta melhorou o suficiente para ser reaberta.

Em primeiro lugar queria entender porque o voto ocorre de forma tão estranha.

E os moderadores precisarão começar a tomar providências porque isto está prejudicando a comunidade, especialmente em reaberturas de conteúdo ruim que a pessoa fica mais desesperada porque tem poucos casos e fica mais difícil atingir medalha se ela ficar pulando muita coisa.

De qualquer forma, o botão de "Pular" está aí para todo caso que você não tenha certeza do que está fazendo. Vamos ter uma pouco mais de cuidado?

Tem gente que deve estar pensando "que alivio, escapei, porque eu ia votar pra reabrir, e depois pra fechar, mas não deu tempo, 5 chegaram antes".

E tem um outro detalhe, quem costuma não se preocupar com as filas costuma fazer outras coisas que complicam a administração da comunidade. Então é bom ficar de olho em tudo. Estamos em um momento que está vindo muito conteúdo bem complicado, sem condições de responder como deve ser em um site de Q&A, então o cuidado deve ser maior e não menor.

Comment: Quando eu comecei a participar da fila sempre achei que o "Pular" não deveria existir porque as pessoas tenderiam a pular tudo e não analisar. Hoje percebo que é bem o contrário, que o botão é pouco utilizado. Parece que as pessoas se sentem na obrigação de analisar tudo.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss "analisar" :)

Comment: To achando melhor tirar a medalha e deixar só quem quer realmente ajudar

Comment: Eu (vou falar por mim) costumo gastar pelo menos 1 minuto analisando a análise antes de dar o voto. Em caso de dúvida, ou se for num assunto que eu não entendo muito, clico logo em pular. Mas como ser humano, posso ser suscetível a um voto equivocado, sem falar em raros casos (mas já aconteceu algumas vezes) em querer clicar em "pular" ou "manter fechada" e clicar em "reabrir" sem querer. Claro que, mesmo sem querer, o site não quer nem saber, ou seja, seu clique é de sua responsabilidade. Faz parte. :D

Comment: Por outro lado, vejo isso como um **problema do site** (ou da moderação, não sei). Como diz o ditado: "cada um com seus _pobrema_". Se o site delega análises aos seus usuários e tá achando ruim o resultado, cabe a ele (ou aos seus _comissionados_ moderadores) tomar partido disso e adotar as medidas cabíveis.

Comment: Mas tb acho que seria humanamente impossível que apenas os moderadores fossem habilitados para fazer todas as análises. Creio que é por isso o site adota a postura de que que "_cada usuário é um moderador_". Só acho que as filas de análise deveriam ser moderadas por usuários com uma boa reputação, muito embora isso não seja garantia de análises perfeitas, mas pelo menos já seria alguma coisa. Mas acho que seria interessante saber a % de más análises _versus_ % de boas análises.

Comment: Assim daria para fixar um índice mínimo aceitável, e se a % das boas análises estivessem dentro do mínimo aceitável, teoricamente estaria tudo bem. A perfeição seria ótima, mas é muito difícil.

Comment: Eu pessoalmente pulo quase tudo nessa fila, só aqueles que eu tenho mesmo a certeza é que voto. Prefiro errar por não analisar algo que talvez saiba do que analisar sem ter a certeza.

Comment: @Sam Pior que a questão nem são essas falhas pontuais. Isso a comunidade por si só gerencia, se um clica errado por engano, outros verão que não faz sentido e não deixarão o erro tomar forma. Isso se esses outros usuários estão analisando também, coisa que nem sempre acontece, como foi apontado na pergunta. Mesmos usuários votaram para reabrir a pergunta e 1h depois votaram para fechar sem nenhuma alteração nesse meio tempo, o que fortemente indicaria que não analisaram bem o suficiente ao votarem para reabrir.

Comment: É @AndersonCarlosWoss. Concordo com vc. Acho que isso é uma discussão que tem seu grau de complexidade, e debatendo a gente vai afinando as coisas.

Comment: As vezes caio no mesmo problema do @sam, aperto sem querer no botão errado na hora de avaliação, principalmente quando mudo de reabrir para fechar, claro que me esforço para que isso não aconteça, mas como o Anderson disse, acredito que mesmo errando, haverá outros que não deixarão o erro persistir, já que são 5 votos.

Comment: Constantemente eu me deparo como o motivo "errado" para fechar, pode ser que esteja interpretando de forma errada, ou se encaixa no que o @Maniero falou, quando a pessoa escolhe fechar ela simplesmente marca o que as outras pessoas já escolheram para ganhar a medalha mais rápido.

Comment: Eu não sei como funciona para implementar novas funcionalidades no site, ou se há alguma forma de implementar um recurso novo em um stack em especifico, mas será que não poderiam criar um botão de voltar? Para estes casos de engano ao aperta o botão?

Comment: Outro ponto é achar que esta certo, vou colocar um exemplo aqui que acho que alguns podem discorda, mas esta é a intensão, gerar discussão, as vezes voto para reabrir mesmo que a pergunta não esteja 100%, em casos que a pergunta já esta em um ponto que da para entender, mas precisa se polida, então deixo um comentário com uma dia do que pode ser melhorada, acho que isso estimula o autor a melhorar.

Comment: Já foi discutido e a pessoa deve analisar bem antes de votar, foi decidido que não é para a pessoa errar, se ela tem chance de errar não deve votar, ou até deve ficar longe da fila. Só é uma ajuda quando a pessoa faz com cuidado. E não deve votar para reabrir se a pergunta não está boa o suficiente, isto é mal uso da fila também ou voto. Só deve ser reaberta a pergunta que já está ok, só existe duas formas de perguntas: ok e não ok, e toda que não é ok, é não ok e deve ficar fechada. Você pode transformá-la em ok, aí sim pode votar, mas votos por suposição que será melhorada tá errado.

Comment: Moderadores diamante (MD) tb erram... ou não? Pelo menos o que reparo é que, geralmente, os MDs fecham perguntas fáceis de fechar, aquelas com 2 linhas de texto que não diz nada com nada. Mas vejo dezenas de perguntas enormes, com código e tudo, mas que não são melhores do que aquelas de 2 ou 3 linhas de texto. Ou seja, o MD não analisa a pergunta "maior", que deveria ser fechada, porque é bem mais fácil fechar uma curta de 2 linhas. Não que haja problema nisso, até faz parte do fluxo do site onde os demais usuários podem votar para fechar aliviando a carga sobre os MDs, porém...

Comment: quem não é MD está muito mais sujeito a errar porque tem que analisar,muitas das vezes,textos e códigos grandes, aumentando o risco de errar, em vez de uma pergunta com 2 linhas de texto ou perguntas muito curtas, que são mais fáceis de moderar. Agora,é complicado saber que,depois de uma edição da pergunta que fora fechada,onde o AP incluiu um monte de informações novas e códigos, ela deve ser reaberta ou não. Isso é complicado porque,muitas vezes,no olhômetro e numa lida rápida no novo conteúdo inserido, induz o usuário a votar para reabrir porque ele não vai gastar meia-hora analisando tudo

Comment: e também tem a questão de "votar"...o usuário quer "votar", quer ganhar pontos, quer participar, quer ajudar. Não posso afirmar que haja (pode ser que haja) usuários que saem votando em tudo sem analisar e sem critérios apenas para ganhar pontos e medalhas. Aí o site deve adotar as medidas cabíveis. Mas o que eu queria mesmo era chamar a atenção para a possibilidade de errar na hora de votar, que é muito maior pra quem não é MD,já que os MDs tem o poder de fechar e abrir qualquer coisa a seu critério,e eles também podem estar errando, ou são detentores da verdade (não leia isto de forma ruim)?

Comment: Aliás, os MDs também passam por auditoria como os demais usuários? São interpelados quando erram nas análises? Fica a pergunta.

Comment: Como eu disse antes, se é ruim pro site análises ruins, que ele adote medidas para suspender ou banir usuários que fazem análises ruins com frequência (inclusive eu, se for o caso), assim ele terá um time seleto de bons analistas e ninguém terá dores de cabeça com isso.

Comment: Eu fecho perguntas curtas e longas, claro que as curtas são fáceis, as longas nem sempre, as curtas quase sempre dá para saber que é muito ruim, as longas precisa ter um conhecimento mais específico, aí eu faço o que tem que fazer, pular. O risco de errar é igual pra todo mundo, acontece que alguns resolvem fazer algo no que não entendem ou que precisa muito esforço para analisar e a pessoa não está querendo fazer  esse esforço, aí ela erra porque analisa para fechar mesmo não tendo total condição de fazer isto, e aí a chance de errar é maior, mas é o risco que ela assumiu.

Comment: Claro, moderadores precisam errar menos, mas todos que pularem o que não entendem errarão menos. Ter um erro ou outro não é problema. Ter posições duvidosas não é um problema, mas errar muito e ter erros crassos que todos concordam que é erro, principalmente a pessoa votar contra a si própria sem nenhum mudança é um problema. Se a pessoa fica na dúvida se a pergunta deve ser reaberta é porque ela não deve, ou deixa fechada ou pula. Análise e olhômetro são duas coisas diferentes, a fila é de análise, não de olhômetro.

Comment: Todos passam por auditorias. Em essência ninguém é interpelado quando erram, a não ser quando é continuo e grave. Algumas pessoas deveriam, porque erraram muito, até ganharem a medalha, aí não voltaram mais para a fila de análise