# Rejeitando/Aprovando não escapando da auditoria? Isto tem sido usado a plataforma?

Tags: suporte, filas-de-análise, auditoria

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

Lamentavelmente percebi uma coisa após observar as ações dos analistas que fazem suas análises nas minhas  sugestões de edições para postagens de perguntas e respostas, e com os resultados das auditorias que passei/reprovei, e nas minhas experiências em análises de perguntas e respostas.

Essas foram as minhas conclusões confrontadas igualmente com as minhas ações operando análises em postagens de perguntas e respostas, e das ações de sugerir as edições e posteriores aprovações/reprovações por outros analistas operadores.

Nestas, entendo estar equivocado e buscando o esclarecimento dos seguintes pontos:

1. Como analista para uma pergunta ou resposta cuja linguagem não domino, o melhor é pular? Tenho feito na maioria.

   Mas, também entendo que fazendo isso, estou operando algo nesse sentido:
   outro que se responsabilize pelo conteúdo,  não respondo pelo que não fiz!
2. Como analista para perguntas e respostas, considerando ainda que não domino a linguagem, mas, tem já alguma visualização sem qualquer voto negativo, e o objeto da análise está claro (pra quem entende/não entende) e, igualmente apresentável,  devo aprovar? Ou repito a ação do item 1?
3. Toda análise que “finalizo”, onde operou uma ação por parte de auditoria, percebo errônea ou não, os mais experientes que me ensinem, mas opera que:

   a. só as respostas/perguntas que rejeitamos na auditoria são passíveis de  nos “privar” das **reprovações**?

   b. as auditorias não auditam perguntas/respostas “boas/ótimas” merecedoras de aprovaçōes? Obviamente resultando que:
   Na dúvida é melhor rejeitar, e, muitos operadores podem estar ciente desse recurso a operando esse artifício para não cair em reprovações pela auditorias?
4. A plataforma percebe os indicadores de aprovação/reprovação do operador entendendo o que cito acima?

   Seria o caso das auditorias perceberem os analistas e suas ações para respostas não aprovadas merecedoras das aprovações considerando os dados das ações “pular” + “rejeitar”?

Comment: Retirei as tags anteriores, pois pelo que ententi vc quer saber como funcionam as filas de análise e a auditoria das mesmas (por isso acho que a tag "suporte" seja mais adequada, pois ela se refere a "Pedidos de ajuda quanto ao uso do site"). Mas isso foi o que entendi... :-)

Comment: Sobre a primeira pergunta, [não há problema nenhum em pular uma revisão](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252195). *"outro que se responsabilize pelo conteúdo"* - na verdade, se vc não entende sobre o assunto, o melhor é pular mesmo, e deixar para outra pessoa que entende. Pular não é "jogar a culpa/responsabilidade" para outro. Até porque se vc resolve revisar sobre algo que não entende (ou faz sem prestar atenção), pode acabar acontecendo [isso](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7606/112052)

Comment: Há critérios de revisão que se aplicam independentemente da linguagem/tecnologia visada na pergunta/resposta. Se alguns deles não forem cumpridos pode/deve revisar de acordo, mesmo que não domine esses "assuntos".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Como analista para uma pergunta ou reposta onde a linguagem não domino, o melhor é pular? Tenho feito na maioria.

Geralmente sim, melhor que causar um problema por desconhecimento. [Voluntarismo](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voluntarismo) não é bom.

> Mas, também entendo que fazendo isso, estou operando algo nesse sentido: outro que se responsabilize pelo conteúdo, não respondo pelo que não fiz!

Sim, não podemos nos responsabilizar por tudo, especialmente coisas que não dominamos devemos delegar.

> Como analista para perguntas e respostas, considerando ainda que não domino a linguagem, mas, tem já alguma visualização sem qualquer voto down, e o objeto da análise está claro (pra quem entende/não entende) e, igualmente apresentável, devo aprovar? Ou repito a ação do item 1?

Não me parece que não ter negativo tenha alguma coisa a ver com a análise da fila de edição. E todo o parágrafo é estranho para mim, mas na dúvida não tome atitude alguma, a não ser pular.

> a. só as repostas/perguntas que rejeitamos na auditoria são passíveis de nos “privar” das reprovaçōes?

Não sei se entendi bem, o texto está um pouco confuso, mas se for que você errar na auditoria vai acumulando estatística negativa e em algum momento poderá ser suspenso da fila de análise por algum período.

> b. as auditorias não auditam perguntas/respostas “boas/ótimas” merecedoras de aprovaçōes? Obviamente resultando que: Na dúvida é melhor rejeitar, e, muitos operadores podem estar ciente desse recurso a operando esse artifício para não cair em reprovações pela auditorias?

Não sei dizer o que acontece, mas a auditoria deveria verificar erros, não importa quais. E não é apenas ela usada, também há verificações manuais e algumas pessoas já foram suspensas por causa disto. Em geral vejo as pessoas sendo mais suspensas por aprovar qualquer coisa do que por reprovar equivocadamente.

> A plataforma percebe os indicadores de aprovação/reprovação do operador entendendo o que cito acima?

Não tenho nada oficial sobre isto, mas a auditoria foi feita para dar indicadores de acerto e erro das pessoas nas filas de análise.

> Seria o caso das auditorias perceberem os analistas e suas ações para respostas não aprovadas merecedoras das aprovações considerando os dados das ações “pular” + “rejeitar”?

Talvez, ou talvez já seja assim.

A questão é que tudo ali existe para tentar fazer com que as pessoas façam o que devem fazer, tentar acertar o máximo possível. Ela não é perfeita, mas ajuda identificar padrões ruins de algumas pessoas. No resumo de tudo, faça a análise da melhor forma que puder, só isso importa. Isto significa que deve pular o que não tem certeza do que está fazendo. Pode haver alguma injustiça em algum caso, mas isto é raro, pleo menos para dar suspensão, há mais injustiça onde não é identificado mecanicamente que algum usuário está errado muito. De qualquer forma o principal motivo para existir a auditoria é para evitar o abuso deliberado, secundariamente para evitar o erro legítimo constante.

Comment: Eu não sei onde quer chegar, mas os moderadores estão sempre olhando se a fila de análise está sendo usada de forma correta e o objetivo é apenas fazer o certo, o resto não é importante, é até melhor que os critérios exatos não sejam conhecidos.

Comment: Acho perfeitamente normal reprovar mais que aprovar, não tem argumento no que está expondo apenas opinião.