# Devemos editar uma pergunta que está/será fechada e possivelmente removida?

Tags: debate, edição

Obviamente que editar uma pergunta para salvá-la sempre é bom. A pergunta aqui é se devemos fazer pequenas edições como formatações, correções de digitação, gramática e ortografia.

Se a pergunta está ruim e não parece ter salvação ou sua edição não a salva, me pergunto, pra que editar para deixar mais bonitinho algo que não tem futuro e provavelmente será removida?

Tenho visto muita edição deste tipo e questiono a validade disto. Tenho minha opinião e muitos já devem saber :P

Tem algum critério pra determinar isto?

Comment: Eu só acho ruim quando a pergunta já está fechada e a edição não é suficiente para reabri-la, pois aí ela vai para a fila de reabertura e existe o risco de [votarem para reabrir](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7606/112052) sem analisar direito... Quando ela ainda não está fechada, eu uso critérios parecidos com o Anderson e hugocsl (conforme respostas abaixo)

Comment: Eu geralmente edito (antes de fechar pra não entrar na fila), em muitas situações para deixar claro o que tinha ali, e pra não ficar caracterizado que foi fechado por mero engano. por exemplo, um código que nao salva a pergunta mas estava escondido, ou uma formatação ruim que não foi motivo do fechamento, mas pode ser interpretada como tendo sido. Cabe a resposta padrão "depende" :D

Answer (score 11):

Dependendo do que é eu edito mesmo votando para fechar.

Na minha opinião, não é porque eu decidi que a pergunta deve ser fechada que ela será realmente fechada e, portanto, faço a edição melhorando a pergunta de forma a facilitar a análise dos outros usuários.

E se, por ventura, a pergunta não for fechada no final das contas, ela estará, no mínimo, um pouco menos pior.

Se o problema é tão grosseiro que uma edição pequena não melhorará em nada, acabo deixando por sem editar.

Comment: Concordo, eu não entendo nada de PHP por exemplo, mas quando vejo que a pergunta está fechada, e o código todo mal formatado, até mesmo fora do snippet, eu opto por editar, pois é a falta de formatação as vezes que pode ter causado o mal entendimento ou pode ter ocasionado a falta de parte do código, como descrevi na minha resposta. []´s

Answer (score 6):

Não é uma resposta para todos os casos.

Boa parte das perguntas são de novatos, pessoas que não percebem que se escreverem uma `<div>` dessa forma por exemplo ela não vai aparecer depois que a pergunta for publicada. É um erro trivial de quem não entende como funciona a ferramenta, mas que muitas vezes deixa a pergunta "não clara", dificulta o entendimento, e se não clicar para editar vc não vai ver que no meio do texto tinha uma tag HTML "escondida".

Eu já vi perguntas fechadas, que lendo desconfiei que poderia ter um código oculto. Pois o AP falou "eu fiz assim:" e não tinha nada depois... Aí clicando em Editar vi que o código estava lá, só não estava formatado. *(são inúmeros exemplos desse tipo, não vou procurar um para postar aqui, quem é mais experiente já deve ter passado por isso)*.

Resumindo, muitas vezes a "falta de código" da pergunta é um simples erro de formatação de código por parte do AP. E se não for feita a edição pode ficar para sempre no esquecimento e fechada por não estar clara etc... Não é uma resposta para todos os casos, mas é uma situação que a edição é válida ao meu ver.

Comment: Mas aí revelar o código não é uma simples formatação, é uma formatação que possivelmente salva a pergunta.

Comment: @Maniero nem sempre salva a pergunta, as vezes eu formato um código ou outro que não faz parte do meu conhecimento, e não sei julgar se está claro e se faz sentido, apenas coloco como "código" usando as ferramentas do editor de texto. então pode ser que salve, ou não salve, pois o código é ruim, mesmo formatado.

Answer (score 6):

Acredito que haja diferença entre pergunta ruim e pergunta mal formada.

Pergunta ruim tem que ser abandonada e ponto final.

Agora para pergunta mal formada tem que se levar em conta que os usuários novos normalmente desconhecem como formatar o texto com markdown e obtêm um resultado visual terrível, os desestimulando a progredir com a formulação da questão. A edição nesses casos demonstra o interesse da comunidade em acolher o questionamento e o fechamento, da questão, fornece o motivo qual impede a comunidade de levar uma solução.

O porém, como lembrado nos comentários, esse tipo de edição automaticamente leva a questão para fila de análise de reabertura, criando atividade desnecessária para os revisores e correndo o risco de uma reabertura indevida.

Se possível poderia existir uma ferramenta onde o usuário, com reputação suficiente para reabrir uma pergunta, quando fizer a edição *pudesse ou não* indicar a pergunta para fila de análise de reabertura. No caso de edições feitas por usuários que não possuem reputação suficiente para reabrir uma pergunta não prosseguissem para fila de análise de reabertura.

Mas como essa ferramenta não existe, o critério é caso a caso. 
Deveria o editor avaliar o resultado de suas edições antes de aplicá-las.

Caso o conteúdo após as melhorias possa vir a ser aproveitado ou revele potencial para uma futura reflexão é justo que se aplique as edições e a critério do editor colocar um comentário de orientação ou pedido de esclarecimento.

Ao contrário, onde mesmo com as modificações o conteúdo permaneça avesso a qualquer tipo de potencial qualitativo, as edições devem ser descartadas.

Pelo menos essas são minhas impressões até o momento, sou usuário do StackOverflow a pouco tempo e conforme eu ganhe experiência e assimile a cultura da comunidade talvez minhas impressões a respeito possam mudar, mas no momento é assim que vejo.

Comment: É o que eu penso, mas para minha surpresa nem todo mundo acha o mesmo, então parece que ficará assim, um monte de edição que ajuda em nada e que será descartada porque a pergunta é ruim, e não tem votos ou está negativada, portanto será removida. Muito trabalho para nada útil. Enquanto isso edições que poderia salvar perguntas não estão sendo feitas.

Comment: Não sei se sabe, mas quando uma pergunta fechada é editada ela automaticamente entra na fila de reabertura.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss, Eu conjecturei a possibilidade dessa automaticidade deixar de existir por parte de uma ferramenta hipotética onde o usuário pudesse escolher se a pergunta deveria ou não ser encaminhada para a fila de reabertura. Desculpe-me, a você e a quem ler, se fui nebuloso em meu comentário.

Comment: Só pra atualizar: agora por na fila ou não é opcional. Tem um checkbox para isso.

Answer (score -2):

Eu cometi um erro na concepção da pergunta e as pessoas entenderam errado o que quis dizer. EU não queria saber se era para arrumar uma pergunta que potencialmente salvaria a pergunta, por exemplo fazer um código aparecer. Eu estava pegando os casos em que você muda um detalhe ou outro e nada mudam a pergunta continua ruim, será fechada ou continuará assim, provavelmente negativada e a edição vai pro lixo junto com a pergunta.

Na minha opinião essas edições são desperdício de recurso e as pessoas deveriam se concentrar em coisas mais efetivas e usar esse tempo com algo que pode salvar perguntas, com algo que possa gerar um resultado positivo. Claro quem nem sempre é fácil definir o que pode ajudar ou não, mas tem muitos casos que dá e acho que deveríamos escolher melhor o que gastar nosso tempo pra produzir um resultado melhor. Digo isso principalmente porque muita coisa que precisa ser feita não está sendo feita, enquanto coisas inúteis estão.

Me surpreendeu as respostas aqui e fica claro que minha tentativa de alertar para o fato não deu certo e vamos continuar gastando tempo com o que não produz resultado. Uma pena, mas comunidade é assim mesmo.

---

Passado um tempo minha visão parecia certa. As pessoas gastaram esforços editando o irrelevante, cansaram e foram embora, e cada vez mais não tem ajuda comunitária. Eu tentei alertar mas não tive sucesso. Quando o cobertor é curto tem que cobrir o que é mais importante.

Comment: As três respostas não respondem o que foi perguntado? Pela sua descrição aqui eu entendi plenamente a pergunta e respondi de acordo. Também não entendi a sua surpresa.

Comment: Não é questão de responder, é debate, cada um põe sua opinião. Eu concordei com a do Augusto, mas não com a sua e do Hugo porque elas acham que deve se gastar tempo com coisas inúteis. A sua ainda dá uma margem de interpretação. Mas cada um pode ter sua opinião, não existe certo ou errado absoluto. Só que não existe uma resposta contundente que dê para começar pedir para as pessoas pararem de gastar tempo com algo inútil e partir para o que pode trazer mais resultados.

Comment: É que o primeiro parágrafo da sua resposta basicamente diz "ninguém respondeu o que eu queria ler", isso não abre muito o leque para debates. Na minha opinião a sua opinião se resume a "eu achei isso ruim, então todos devem achar ruim e ninguém deve alterá-la"; a minha visão sobre isso estaria mais para "eu achei isso ruim, mas vou corrigir o que está a meu alcance pois os outros podem não achar tão ruim assim". Entendi certo?

Comment: Sim, foi exatamente isso que eu quis dizer, eu queria ler outra coisa quando fiz a pergunta, acontece, o mundo nunca é do jeito que eu quero. O debate foi feito, eu tenho uma opinião contrária e não pude confirmar o que eu desejava, paciência. O debate foi aberto pra ver a opinião das pessoas, eu não posso agir agora fazendo algo que não seja o que elas querem com clareza. Assim como outras perguntas que eu abri e foram quase ignoradas. Eu até poderia começar fazer do jeito que bem entendo por ninguém ir contra, mas não é legal eu agir sozinho nesta. A abertura do debate era pra obter apoio...

Comment: ... não aconteceu. Eu achei isso ruim, achei que outras pessoas achariam e por isso poderia mexer em algo, como isso não aconteceu ficará do jeito que está. EU tentei corrigir um rumo, mas preciso de apoio pra isso.

Comment: Talvez se apresentasse essa solução mais abertamente ficaria mais fácil analisar. Eu particularmente não vejo como eu poderia colaborar mais deixando de fazer essas micro edições esporádicas. Acredito que muitos outros usuários também não conseguem ver e por isso acabam mantendo essa postura por julgar que assim estão colaborando. A solução deste problema que você propõem se resumia a apenas deixar de editar perguntas ruins ou demandaria fazer algo mais?

Comment: Exatamente isso, as pessoas acham que estão colaborando quando a colaboração é necessária em outro ponto. Eu tentei algo, não deu certo, mas esse é só um problema do site atualmente, a participação está bem baixa de forma geral. Você é uma das poucas pessoas que não reduziu muito a participação útil. Não acho que tenha muito mais o que fazer, tem que contabilizar o prejuízo, esse ano parecia que não poderia piorar mais em relação ao que piorou ano passado, mas aconteceu, e acho que acontecerá de novo ano que vem e a gente já não faz mais algo que ajude a internet ser melhor.

Comment: Consegue ser mais específico quanto ao outro ponto? Eu tenho conhecimento de muitos problemas que há no site, você mais ainda, mas se a ideia é conseguir mais atividade nesse outro ponto, não é mais simples pedir "por favor, vamos fazer mais isso" do que debater sobre "porquê estão fazendo isso"? Talvez os outros usuários não pararam para analisar o problema como você o fez e não entendem o impacto disso; talvez nem tenhamos ferramentas para calcular esse impacto. Entende?

Comment: Eu quis ser mais democrático e esperar o apoio natural, porque se eu falo pra fazer parece que quero impor isso. Na próxima vou ser mais impositivo (claro que sempre poderá ser contestado).

Comment: Mas sugerir é diferente de impor. Com essa discussão me pareceu que a pergunta é um problema XY. Você quer resolver um problema discutindo outro.

Comment: O problema é o mesmo, mas queria primeiro discutir porque eu não tinha certeza se era só eu que via assim.