# Perda de pontos ao longo da madrugada

Tags: debate

Ao longo dos últimos meses (creio que últimos dois ou três) tenho notado que todas as madrugadas eu perco alguns pontos. Inicialmente estava perdendo de 1 a 3 por madrugada, porém, após alcançar os primeiros 300 pontos tenho notado que este número tem crescido drasticamente, chegando a perder 25 pontos.

Sei que há um robô que passa durante a madrugada verificando possíveis fraudes, porém, não justifica a perda de tantos pontos.

Eu passo o dia inteiro no Stack Overflow tentando ajudar da melhor forma possível, sendo ela, editando posts, respondendo, auxiliando novos usuários e etc...

Esta madrugada por exemplo. Saí do computador estava com 580 pontos de reputação, ao abrir o site hoje, me deparei com 564 contabilizados...

Hoje, quais são as justificativas das perdas drásticas de pontos dos usuários? Levando em consideração o longo período que passo no site prestando ajuda a usuários.

Alguém sabe me dizer o que está acontecendo nos últimos meses para estas perdas absurdas de pontuação?

Comment: [Aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/roomba) tem os critérios que o sistema usa para apagar perguntas. Basicamente, se a pergunta se encaixa em um desses critérios, nem vale a pena editar, pois certamente será apagada (a menos que mude algo, como ela ser melhorada e reaberta, etc)

Comment: Muito obrigado pelo link, como dito abaixo, estou me adequando e minhas intenções são apenas de ajuda. Irei ler com calma e absorver o máximo de informações possíveis sobre o assunto.

Answer (score 9):

No seu caso específico é porque você está editando perguntas ruins e que não ajudam salvá-las. Você ganha 2 pontos porque alguém aprovou a edição (que foi inócua). Como a pergunta era ruim ela acaba sendo removida do site, então a edição que você fez não teve valor, e os pontos ganhos com a edição são removidos da sua reputação.

De fato vi muita edição sua que não ajudava nada ou mesmo prejudicava a postagem. Na forma feita passa até a impressão que só faz pelos pontos e não com intuito de ajudar a comunidade. Não posso julgar se foi isso, muitos o fazem sem entender porque está fazendo aquilo e o que ajuda de fato. Meu conselho é repensar em onde ajudar. Ajude no que é útil.

Teve uma discussão em [Devemos editar uma pergunta que está/será fechada e possivelmente removida?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7946/101) mas a conclusão é que isso não importa, ficou decidido ali que seria bom deixar as pessoas perderem tempo editando coisas que não tem salvação. Obviamente eu considerei que isto é abuso do sistema de pontuação e que o esforço da pessoa poderia ser aplicado em momentos mais importantes que realmente ajude a comunidade. Enquanto a pessoa está fazendo essa edição ela não está fazendo em outros lugares úteis.

Não quer dizer que nos casos que não houve reversão de pontos que a edição tenha sido boa. Você pode ter boa intenção, mas quase todas edições que faz não ajudam de fato. EU vi algumas que deveriam ter sido rejeitadas, você mudou o que o autor queria dizer, colocou palavras na boca dele. Só não foi rejeitado porque muitas pessoas passam pela fila de aprovação e votam sem ler nada, e outros cansaram de fazer isso de tanto problema que tem.

Não quero desestimular o seu esforço, mas no momento o que está fazendo tem causado mais problemas que está dando ajuda. Se não desse tanto trabalho eu reverteria manualmente várias edições que fez e foram aprovadas. Pra mim o grosso do ganho de reputação que teve foi indevido (não estou falando de fraude).

Tente se acostumar mais com o padrão da comunidade.

E não houve perdas drásticas ou absurdas, a perda foi mínima. Só não foi quase zero porque a maioria das suas edições não foram úteis.

Passar tempo no site e ajudar usuários são coisas distintas. Fazer algo pode ajudar o usuário, pode ser neutro, e pode ser prejudicial.

Comment: Então como dica, não seria uma boa forma o próprio SO ter uma ferramenta onde seja possível votar pela edição e pontuação? Tenho feito as edições tentando deixar o mais claro possível ao entendimento de todos. Não sei se há um local em específico onde possa ser dada a ideia de quando votar pela edição, também poder votar se serão dados pontos de edição ou não ao editor.

Comment: E ele tem, eu até falei disso na resposta. Mas as pessoas não usam de forma adequada e aprovam coisas ruins. O grande problemas das suas edições não é a pontuação é que elas não deveriam ser feitas.

Comment: Estou me adequando ainda as regras e padrões do SO, sei que ainda tenho muito a aprender, porém, com as tuas observações já sei que deverei ter mais cuidado ao editar e evitar edições em determinados posts. Aos poucos venho lendo (principalmente as postagens do meta) para poder ir me adequando mais. Não leio todas as respostas, mas geralmente as primeiras já posso ter uma ideia do assunto abordados e os meios que são utilizados para evitar futuros problemas.

Comment: @JaksonFischer inclusive, algumas pessoas que aprovaram edições como as que você fez, entraram no rol de suspensão da fila de análise. A fila é justamente para isso, para que pessoas confiram se está ok. Quando falha a edição e vem mais duas pessoas que não analisam corretamente, realmente a situação complica. Eu vejo mais problema em quem aprova do que na edição propriamente dita. Se recusassem, você mesmo perguntaria o que houve de errado e aprenderia mais cedo alguns detalhes.