# Certificado para os usuários da rede

Tags: novo-recurso

O que vocês acham de criar um certificado para os usuários da rede SOpt por realizarem algum feito, como ocorre no GUJ, onde eles dão um certificado por completar um tutorial?

No caso, eu estava pensando em um certificado para coisas mais "sérias" como, certificado de comprovação de que o usuário é um bom membro da rede. Por exemplo, esse certificado seria dado ao atingir 5K ou 10K de reputação, ter uma certa quantia de respostas e uma certa quantia de perguntas, ter ajudado uma determinada quantidade de pessoas, etc.

Logicamente, o certificado poderia ser baixado a qualquer momento (PDF ou imagem). Acho que isso seria bastante interessante. Ademais, possivelmente a qualidade das perguntas e respostas do site melhorariam, devido à esse incentivo aos usuários.

Comment: Olá Jean. Reputação não é um bom parametro para determinar ser um bom membro, tem usuários com mais de 20k que não são bons, infelizmente, e tem usuários com menos de 20k como o  Luiz Vieira que são otimos (da pra citar mais uns 10 bons usuários), numero de respostas também não define muito bem, tem respostas que parecem boas, mas não são e geralmente quando alguém aponta o problema isso acaba virando um pé de guerra, "certificado" só atrairia mais respostas helpdesk, ctrl+c e até gafes, por fim, isso não é uma coisa que nós podemos definir, quem teria que definir é a empresa.

Comment: De qualquer forma já temos as **medalhas**. Incentivar os usuários não é o problema, o problema é a qualidade, é aqui que temos que nos preocupar, se a maior parte da comunidade se preocupasse um pouco mais com isso talvez estaríamos melhor, mas devo dizer que felizmente estou acompanhando 3 usuários relativamente novos que entenderam bem o propósito do site e estão ajudando bastante, algo que é recente, espero ver mais usuários interessados nessas partes importantes, me trouxe esperança :D

Comment: Não é exatamente um certificado, mas hj existe o flair: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/flair

Comment: Aqui quando completa um tutorial ganha uma [medalha](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/84/informed) certificando que fez o tutorial até o final. O mesmo acontece com outras atividades.

Answer (score 6):

Se a ideia é incentivar os usuários a melhorarem as perguntas e respostas... não sei.

A premissa do site é - e acredito que sempre foi, embora hoje não pareça tanto assim - incentivar a qualidade através do *gamification* e da moderação comunitária.

Os votos e a pontuação obtida ou perdida com eles já servem como uma espécie de incentivo. Claro que não é perfeito, há muitas distorções: respostas com gambiarras horrendas, com SQL injection, código que nem compila, ou com informações corretas mas que não respondem à pergunta, etc, e mesmo assim ganham positivo; ou o contrário, respostas boas que não ganham o devido reconhecimento. Sem contar os que respondem qualquer coisa de qualquer jeito atrás de pontinhos fáceis, os que criam outras contas para votar em si mesmo, etc.

Mas de qualquer forma o sistema de votos/reputação tem o objetivo de incentivar uma busca pela qualidade (afinal, eles servem para dar aos visitantes do site uma indicação rápida sobre a qualidade daquele conteúdo). Se funciona ou não, é outra história.

Também temos as [medalhas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/badges), que *teoricamente* deveriam servir para incentivar comportamentos "bons" ou "desejáveis" ([isso foi inclusive dito por um dos fundadores do site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/97225/401803)), e de certa forma não deixa de ser uma "premiação" pelos feitos de um usuário. E claro que também há distorções, como por exemplo gente que [faz revisões na fila de análise sem analisar nada](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7606/112052) (**a impressão que dá** é que é só pra ganhar [medalha](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/83/steward)), etc. Esse é o problema do *gamification*, sempre tem quem realmente encara como um "joguinho" que pode ser burlado, e acaba encontrando brechas e desvirtuando tudo.

Enfim, atualmente já temos mecanismos que servem - ou deveriam servir - para incentivar os usuários a buscarem mais qualidade e não desvirtuar o site. Não são perfeitos, mas é o que temos e deveríamos usar melhor. Então eu pergunto:

**Qual seria o diferencial desse certificado em relação ao que já existe?**

Se ele for baseado nos critérios mencionados (pontos, quantidade de perguntas/respostas, etc), isso não garante que o usuário é "bom" ou "ruim". Temos todas as combinações possíveis no site: usuários com alta e baixa pontuação, com poucas ou muitas medalhas, com contribuições de qualidade boa e ruim, e quantidade grande ou pequena de perguntas ou respostas. Se alguém participa por tempo suficiente, sendo "cuidadoso", pode obter pontuação alta mesmo com contribuições ruins (afinal, voto positivo dá 10 pontos, aceitação dá 15 e negativo só tira 2, então responder *help-desk* acaba "compensando", ainda mais se a pergunta for de um iniciante que por não ter muito conhecimento acaba aceitando qualquer coisa).

Criar mais um item de *gamification* (pois no fundo é isso: vou atingir tais marcos para obter tal item) poderia até incentivar as pessoas a participarem mais, mas meu receio é que ocorra a mesma distorção que os mecanismos atuais já possuem: a corrida desenfreada para obtê-lo, e aí o tiro sai pela culatra. E como já vimos que distorções acontecem bastante com votos e medalhas, eu diria que a chance de acontecer com qualquer outro mecanismo é grande. Ainda mais se esse mecanismo for baseado em algo que já é imperfeito e com distorções. Eu prefiro primeiro consertar as distorções atuais e só depois talvez-quem-sabe pensar em adicionar mais coisas.

---

Eu tenho uma opinião sobre o *gamification* (que talvez fuja um pouco do escopo da pergunta): no fundo, ele não faz tanta diferença assim na qualidade. Quem quer fazer boas contribuições, o fará independente de pontos ou medalhas, e quem não liga pra qualidade vai fazer as coisas de qualquer jeito, também sem ligar pra pontuação/medalhas. Claro que os pontos ou medalhas *podem* servir de incentivo, mas aí creio que varia conforme a pessoa, e não sei se é algo que influencia tanto assim de modo geral.

Claro, não tenho dados para confirmar isso, pode ser só minha impressão, mas enfim: da forma que foi proposto este certificado, não acho que ele vá resolver os problemas que já temos nos mecanismos atuais de incentivo à participação e busca da qualidade.