# Precisamos de melhores textos explicativos nos motivos de fechamento?

Tags: debate, razões-fechamento, ux

Eu já digo que acho que sim. Ultimamente tem aparecido muitos usuários não só novatos em programação, ou novatos no SO, aparentemente são novatos na internet (mesmo que não sejam de fato, e não conseguem usar o site corretamente até nos aspectos mais básicos. Eu acho até que outras mudanças precisariam ser feitas, eles não estão conseguindo usar o editor corretamente, não conseguem escrever no lugar certo, não acham onde clicar em funções óbvias e encontram outras dificuldades, até mesmo para dizer o que querem. Mas o maior problema é que mesmo com alguma ajuda não melhora muito a situação.

Uma coisa que notamos é que as instruções do que fazer quando a pergunta é fechada não são seguidas. Alguns casos a pessoa não lê e temos pouco a fazer, mas há casos que provavelmente uma instrução um pouco melhor possa produzir resultados melhores. Se concorda e tem alguma sugestão a hora é agora.

Sugira um texto melhor para substituir o texto atual de cada fechamento que você acha que tem problemas.

O ideal é não mudar tanto, não tirar partes importantes, mas de alguma forma, com texto ou formatação fazer o usuário perceber melhor o que ocorreu e, principalmente, o que fazer para reverter a situação.

Acho importante colocar *links* específicos para a pessoa ir direto no que lhe ajuda, manda para a Central de Ajuda não é muito amistoso. E quem sabe precisemos melhorar os textos de ajuda.

O limite do tamanho do texto é 400 caracteres.

[Exemplo de texto](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/7448/101).

Comment: Dá até pra tirar a interrogação do título :)

Comment: È que alguém pode discordar... :)

Comment: Eu acho que uma parte importante dessas sequer devia ter um limite tão baixo de caracteres, até para poder escrever coisas mais simpáticas e que orientem com mais clareza. Quanto à pessoa não seguir, sinto muito, o ônus deveria ser delas de procurar a solução. Acho que o maior problema do site é querer agradar demais, e na prática isso castigar o publico alvo e premiar o fuçador (aproveitando o termo que eu usei em 2014 no meta, pra diferenciar o novato do folgado, e alguns não gostaram). Em resumo, precisamos realmente melhorar todos os textos e defendo isso de longa data.

Comment: Um link para a minha nova pergunta [A minha pergunta foi fechada e agora?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7470) ficava mesmo bem :p

Comment: "*Sugira um texto melhor para substituir o texto atual de cada fechamento que você acha que tem problemas.*" Será melhor uma resposta com todas as sugestões ou uma para cada mensagem?

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss acho que separado ajuda votar

Comment: Existe alguma discussão no âmbito de [As mensagens de erro devem se desculpar?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2539/5878) para as mensagens de fechamento? Pergunto se já foi discutido se é interessante termos mensagens *mais humanas* ou mais diretas. Aliás, a limitação de 400 caracteres inclui também os links, correto? Os links mágicos funcionam nessas mensagens?

Comment: Por pior que os textos sejam (ou não), acho que a maior parte do problema (não inteiramente) esta na disposição de como o texto é apresentado. Por mais incomodo que um modal seria e que mesmo que muitos não leiam e saiam clicando em alerts, ainda sim acho que uma mensagem fixa que acompanhe o scroll somente na pergunta especifica e somente para o autor, seria um pouco mais eficiente. Não um texto gigante, mas algo assim: "sua pergunta foi fechada, mas você pode conseguir reabri-la se corrigir os problemas, clique aqui para mais detalhes", então nos tais detalhes teria um modal [...]

Comment: [...] ou página com dicas. Eu entendo que muitos irão ler e discordar de mim nisto, mas acreditem se puderem (me dar esse voto de confiança), usuários inexperientes, mesmo que experientes na área de TI ou apressados demais procuram fazer "leitura dinamica" de tudo, mas existe um problema na "leitura dinamica", ela exige pratica para tentar absorver o que esta em sua frente, o que na verdade a maioria até acha que consegue, mas na verdade acabam entendendo errado. Aliais vejo muitas pessoas em outros lugares que leem coisas por cima e falam besteiras depois. Penso que quando o usuário [...]

Comment: [...] tem uma mensagem informativa com detalhes o suficiente, mas entregue da forma que é hoje, ele esta preocupado com outras coisas, ainda mais se for novo, apresentar uma mensagem amigavel primeiro, mesmo que leve um clique para chegar a parte técnica de como reabrir a pergunta, seria dar um incentivo ou melhor experiencia. Claro que isso é mais uma ideia de UX e talvez alguém venha e rebata todas minhas palavras, ainda sim irei formular uma ideia de como acredito que seria o ideal em uma resposta (assim que possivel)