# Precisamos de um novo editor de texto

Tags: novo-recurso, edição, ux

Eu sei, não será feito, mesmo assim acho que o problema está se agravando e algo precisa ser feito, pelo menos vou alertar.

Minha estimativa bem por cima é que algo em torno de 80/90% das postagens de usuários novatos são mal formatadas porque eles não conseguem se entender com o editor. Eles não entendem o *markdown*, não entendem os ícones acima, não entendem as peculiaridades do editor, o que acontece ali, o que fazer, não conseguem seguir instruções.

Mesmo usuários que usam o site há algum tempo ainda erram muito, eu diria que passa dos 50%. É verdade que muitos simplesmente não ligam, eles só querem uma solução para seu problema, e não estão interessados em colaborar, não querer tornar aquilo fácil para quem vai ajudar, útil para outras pessoas, não querem evoluir, é puro egoísmo ou egocentrismo. Estes casos não tem muito o que fazer, embora a UI proibir o erro até onde dá já ajudaria.

O problema não é só o editor, eles não acham os "botões" que acionam coisas básicas, não entendem o sistema de *tags*, não conseguem escrever coisas compreensíveis, não entendem lógica básica sobre problemas, ou seja, não estão preparado para programar ou até mesmo resolver coisas mais simples que programação. Geralmente poderíamos considerar essas pessoas como público não alvo, mas a SE os considera público alvo e temos que lidar com isto. Pelo menos ela poderia preparar a UX do site para facilitar a vida destas pessoas. Isto é especialmente válido para o SOpt, e provavelmente outros sites internacionais onde a educação precária (por escolha dessas pessoas) é tão comum.

E é preciso um *wizard* muito mais sofisticado que o que está sendo planejado há meses (sinceramente de tão simples que é, o que foi apresentado é coisa para se fazer em uma semana, e olhe lá).

Como depoimento pessoal tenho usado o Quora, que tem vantagens e desvantagens em relação ao SO, o que me impressiona lá é que não tem postagens mal formatadas, e praticamente não tem uso de recursos de edição de postagens. Até pode editar igual aqui, mas não há incentivo, é até meio escondido, quase ninguém usa, mas as pessoas, a maioria completamente leiga, postam textos melhores. Este problema é culpa da teimosia da SE em insistir com esse editor que não serve para programadores que não podem ser considerados profissionais (no sentido de qualidade, e não sobre ser remunerado) como é o grosso do público que temos aqui.

Comment: Sei não. Me lembro a primeira vez que postei uma pergunta achei o editor bem intuitivo. Eu penso que a maioria novata tem é preguiça de entender e posta de qualquer jeito. Mas acho que algumas coisinhas podem até ser melhoradas ou mais claras.

Comment: Melhorar? Sim, tudo pode e deve ser melhorado. Mas as possíveis melhorias resolverão os factos que aponta: *(...)não conseguem seguir instruções*, *não conseguem escrever coisas compreensíveis, não entendem lógica básica sobre problemas (...) não estão preparado para programar ou até mesmo resolver coisas mais simples que programação*.

Comment: O editor segue o padrão de qualquer editor. Só não consegue trabalhar com ele quem de facto não tem o mínimo interesse por querer usá-lo convenientemente.

Comment: O *markdown* pode ser um problema, mas quem não se sente motivado/interessado/curioso para saber como funciona não tem os requisitos mínimos para ser "um programador". Como diz o Bacco [aqui](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7465/precisamos-de-melhores-textos-explicativos-nos-motivos-de-fechamento#comment28880_7465): *(...) o maior problema do site é querer agradar demais, e na prática isso castigar o publico alvo e premiar o fuçador ...*. Eu também não sabia *"markdown"*.

Comment: @ramaral eu concordo, mas é fato que onde tem um editor melhor as coisas funcionam melhor. Acho que é uma ajuda, a alternativa é continuarmos tendo muitos problemas. Não vai resolver todos eles, mas seria um passo. Mas se o pessoal achar que nem vale o esforço pra mim tá ok, o problema não se resolverá sozinho, vai continuar ruim e os usuários vão continuar recebendo negativos por causa disto. Por mim, podia inclusive "proibir" a participação de pessoas quem não tem condição **mínima** de ser programador, mas não é a política atual adotada, então precisamos de soluções.

Comment: Eu não sou contra possíveis melhorias. Tenho a certeza que haverá algumas que ajudarão e isso é bom para a comunidade. Proibir está fora de questão. Foi apenas um desabafo ...

Comment: @Maniero "proibir" conteúdo que não tem condição mínima é bom pra todos, inclusive para quem não tem a tal condição. O SOen praticamente "acabou" pra qq coisa muito avançada, e olha que lá o pessoal é mão pesada. Eu já previa essa "desgraça" [naquele post antigo](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2096/70), e foi [dito e feito](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fdf8u.png). O pessoal esquece que não precisa ser usuário para consultar o SOpt, então não precisa "todo mundo" postar, e sim, priorizar quem tem como acrescentar, seja com dúvida relevante ou resposta. O resto se beneficia lendo.

Comment: @Bacco eu concordo, e acho que todos sabem disto, mas como nada é feito sobre isto, precisamos melhor a situação atual e dar menos trabalho, e tentar salvar o que é postado, porque é fato que as pessoas não vão se afastando naturalmente como alguns pregam, só piora, e acho que já estamos mais ou menos no mesmo patamar do SOen, quase tudo o que é postado agora ajuda só o usuário que perguntou, e olhe lá... mas é o que temos

Comment: [De interesse](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/378057/1328704).

Comment: @JNat e virá pra cá quando estiver concluído? O fluxo deverá ser idêntico ou podemos adaptar para nossa necessidade?

Comment: Tudo boas perguntas, para as quais ainda não tenho resposta! :) Assim que souber, vocês saberão ;)