# Vamos "ganhar" o novo wizard de criar uma pergunta?

Tags: debate, novo-recurso

Acho que já fazem alguns meses (5, talvez) que vi pela primeira vez o *wizard* para se criar uma pergunta no Stack Overflow em Inglês:

[image]

Já faz tanto tempo que vi que chego a me perguntar se isso um dia chegará à nossa comunidade. Acho que tenho essa dúvida já que, por ser relativamente novo na comunidade, ainda não tenho uma boa noção de quanto tempo demoram para migrar uma *feature* do site principal para cá.

Pessoalmente, penso que esse novo formulário traria uma certa melhoria na qualidade das perguntas dos usuários novatos, que podem não saber ao certo como o site funciona.

O que vocês acham? Demora muito para chegar? E o mais importante: será benéfico, certo?

Comment: Espero que nunca venha. Acredito que vai causar mais confusão do que supostamente melhorar a demanda de perguntas que têm por aí.

Comment: Relacionada [Precisamos de um novo editor de texto](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7466/5878)

Comment: Ainda não temos uma resposta oficial, mas vamos comunicar à equipa que está a trabalhar nessa funcionalidade o interesse dos SOs internacionais :)

Comment: @JNat Já temos algum resultado divulgado sobre o wizard no SOen? Pois se ele de fato foi benéfico lá, seria um bom motivo para tentarmos aqui..

Comment: Ainda não, @hkotsubo: precisamente por isso ainda não tenho uma resposta para vocês :)

Comment: Relacionado: [Baixa qualidade em perguntas de novatos](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7165/75104)

Comment: Editor de texto é muito ruim,quando coloca algum tipo de código ficou uma parte com formatação e outra não.

Comment: Engraçado que na imagem acima podemos ver a opção "i need a hardware recomendation". Engraçado o fato da SOpt não permitir perguntas relacionadas a hardware

Comment: @riki481 Eu não usei esse wizard, mas **acho** que se escolher as opções de recomendação, provavelmente ele deve direcionar o usuário para [esse](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com) ou [esse](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com) site, já que no SOen esse tipo de pergunta [também é off topic](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/169936/401803)

Comment: @JNat nada ainda?

Comment: Lamento, @Maniero, mas não tenho novidades nenhumas, não... :\