# Página de perguntas recentes com muitos votos negativos

Tags: debate, voto-contra, votos

Estive analisando as perguntas mais recentes, da página atual até a 7, e notei que a maioria das perguntas são perguntas negativadas, estão em pendência, duplicadas, fechadas, etc.

Notei também que estas perguntas estão sendo feitas por usuários novos, com poucos pontos de reputação, que provavelmente não estão fazendo uma [boa pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Isto para mim, parece ser um problema que pode deixar uma má imagem para o SOpt. 
Com base nesse problema, fiquei pensando: *Quais atitudes poderiam evitar este tipo de acontecimento? Se os usuários não estão fazendo o tour corretamente, não estão se esforçando para fazer as perguntas,  teria algo que poderia ser feito para "forçá-los" a aprenderem a fazer perguntas melhores?*

Sei que os usuários precisam ir atrás do conteúdo, e que ao fazer uma pergunta, a barra lateral do site já informa muitas dicas sobre como fazer uma pergunta. Mas e se deixar um texto bem informativo acima da `textbox` na primeira pergunta feita pelos usuários? Será que iria ajudá-los a melhorar este quadro de perguntas negativas?

Comment: Acho que é preguiça de ler o tour mesmo. Mas também estou com preguiça em pensar numa solução.

Comment: Talvez força-los a fazer o tour antes de poderem fazer uma pergunta pode diminuir esse número

Comment: Eu realmente acho que a "entrada faciltada" não ajuda. Creio que realmente a pessoa devesse ter um material introdutório melhor ANTES de poder fazer as perguntas, e não apenas o Tour (mas aí já seria outro site e outro sistema, já pedimos muitas coisas mais simples que não acontecerão) -  Opinião do Bacco pessoa, e não moderador: A empresa e o site foram feitos com uma mentalidade, mas acho que as pessoas que mantém o site hoje não  tem mais os princípios e objetivos originais. Acredito também que as prioridades atuais da empresa são totalmente inadequadas para que o site venha a evoluir.

Comment: O maior problema são as pessoas que votam negativo em outros usuários por vingança, tem pessoas que fazem isto e não é legal, cabe até punição. Se preocupe mais com isso, se souber de alguém que faz isso fale pra gente. Negativar perguntas ruins é o que deve ser feito. O ideal é até ajudar melhorar, mas quase todo mundo cansou de fazer isto, é enxugar gelo, ninguém quer se comprometer com sua própria pergunta e terceiriza todo o problema para outras pessoas que estão aqui de boa vontade sem ganhar nada. É justo? Se tiver uma barreira de entrada resolve o problema dos negativos.

Comment: Negativo deve ser visto como um incentivo para melhorar. Eu sei que as pessoas não enxergam assim, mas porque elas não querem ler nada, não querem se comprometer, querem tudo na m]ao. Não tem muito o que fazer. A única possibilidade é a plataforma exigir que a pessoa leia pelo menos o tour e quem sabe mais alguma barreira. Dar melhores ferramentas para os usuários ajudarem quando tá ruim sem criar muito atrito seria bom também.

Comment: @Bacco uma análise de conduta baseada em perguntas e respostas para uma aprovação no cadastro. O que acha?

Comment: @Maniero nós já temos as ferramentas necessárias para _"ajudar quando tá ruim"_. O problema é que a pós-correção não vai influenciar na pré-correção.

Comment: Se downvotes fossem do mal então não existiriam e não existiriam dislikes no Youtube também pelo mesmo motivo. Downvote não é para apontar algo que você "odeia", é para apontar "Autor sua postagem tem problemas". E sinceramente se formos obrigados a explicar para cada novo usuario o problema de cada pergunta o que iremos ganhar é apenas mais desafetos, dos 5 anos que estou frequente no site, de todos que tentei orientar só uma minoria procurava melhorar, o resto preferia se fazer de vitima [...]

Comment: [...] isso pq as pessoas chegam aqui achando que o site é HELPDESK (suporte gratuito para resolver problemas aleatórios) e temos obrigação de responder, mesmo que pergunta seja muito mal feita.

Comment: @CypherPotato são bem fracas, dá trabalho, não é tão automatizado quanto deveria, é ferramenta da década retrasada.

Comment: Dois pontos já falados por ai. Muita gente da o downvote, o autor da pergunta, muda, edite, coloca imagem, código e tudo mais que pode, e a pessoa que deu o downvote, nem se preocupa em ir lá e retirar o voto negativo. Outro ponto tb falado, para mim a pergunta deveria começar fechada, e nem aparecer na lista, e só depois que for aprovada seria publicada, resumindo, uma pergunta nova iria para fila de análise e só depois de aprovada seria publicada, e durante esse momento o novato poderia ser melhor instruído.

Comment: @hugocsl tem gente que se preocupa sim em retirar, o problema é que nem sempre a pergunta melhorou de fato e muitas delas são só respondias corretamente depois de muita conversa com o AP e quem já respondeu geralmente é obrigado a ficar revisando as respostas, fora que muitas perguntas soam no final helpdesk e que as conversações entre AP e ARs demonstram claramente isto, o que já é motivo o suficiente para quem votou nem se preocupar em voltar lá e dar atenção as perguntas de qualidade. [...]

Comment: **No entanto** devo admitir @hugocsl, a SO (empresa), nos deve um sistema que notifica perguntas com votos nossos (seja up, down, fechamento ou reabrir), gostaria muito de ser notificado sobre isto, faz anos que nós (SOen, SOpt, etc) cobramos isto, mas a empresa tem preocupações "maiores", como palavras adequadas a tratamentos de gêneros.

Comment: Relacionados: [Baixa qualidade em perguntas de novatos](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7165/75104) e [Vamos “ganhar” o novo wizard de criar uma pergunta?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7892/75104)

Comment: TInham postado isso e apagaram, vou deixar pro pessoal ver que há interesse, mas a SE nã ose interessou muito: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/314304/140010

Comment: Acho que é preguiça e desleixo mesmo. Tem até usuário meio antigo fazendo pergunta em inglês! :/

Comment: Não sei se alguém já mencionou isto, mas acho que deveria até ter um exemplo de uma boa pergunta, para seguir de guia a quem faz uma nova pergunta. Preferencialmente indicando o porque de cada parte da pergunta lá estar. O enquadramento/contexto, o código, os testes, o erro, os screenshots se for caso disso, etc. É bem mais fácil seguir um estilo/estrutura de uma pergunta que a pessoa vê diretamente no construtor da pergunta do que seguir só umas as indicações meio soltas. Eu acho que isso certamente ia melhorar.