# A minha pergunta foi fechada. E agora?

Tags: suporte, perguntas, proposta-para-faq, perguntas-fechadas

Se você está a ler esta pergunta, provavelmente a sua pergunta foi fechada.

A primeira coisa que você deve fazer é parar por um segundo. A segunda é continuar a ler esta pergunta e a resposta.

A cada minuto que passa várias perguntas são criadas neste site. Infelizmente, algumas delas são fechadas num curto espaço de tempo devido a vários motivos, conforme a imagem abaixo.

[image: Motivos de fechamento]

Muito sucintamente, a sua pergunta foi fechada porque vários usuários da comunidade consideraram que a sua pergunta deve ser fechada devido a um ou vários motivos indicados.

Mas isto não é o fim, pois com certeza você tem o melhor interesse em ter a sua pergunta respondida. Então o seu questionamento deve ser:

- O que eu posso fazer para que a minha pergunta fechada seja reaberta?

Comment: Achei esta iniciativa muito interessante e util! Da forma que está, é algo bem direto ao problema tentando ajudar um usuário novo a conseguir perceber o que tem de fazer para que a sua pergunta seja aberta.

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Votos para fechar perguntas](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2673/votos-para-fechar-perguntas)

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento É verdade que a pergunta que você indicou é relacionada a esta mas no meu ver parece-me diferente suficiente para valer uma pergunta e resposta diferente. Se discorda explique qual é o seu ponto de contenção. Tenha em atenção que eu fiz esta pergunta como um guia para ser fornecido como referencia nas perguntas fechadas.

Comment: Olá caro @BrunoCosta, vou tirar o voto de fechamento, não era bem essa que eu queria indicar, mas estou quase certo que o assunto já foi debatido e que seria interessante a sua resposta (que por sinal esta muito bem feita e organizada) ser colocada nela(s), eu só não lembro o link ao certo, estou meio sem tempo de ver, depois indico (talvez). Até breve :)

Answer (score 12):

### Se você é um usuário novo

1. Esta comunidade é para programadores mas alguns tópicos não são aceitos. [Veja quais são os tópicos que nos aceitamos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Adicionalmente de uma olhada no [Manual de como NÃO fazer perguntas](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5483).
2. [Faça o *tour* do site](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour) para ter melhor entendimento como o site funciona.
3. Se ainda tem dúvidas em relação ao funcionamento do site [leia a nossa FAQ](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/699/faq-da-comunidade).

#### Aspetos relevantes que você deve ter em conta como usuário novo

1. [Agradecimentos são feitos através de votos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote).
2. [Aceite a resposta que melhor atendeu o seu problema](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/como-e-por-que-aceitar-uma-resposta). Aceitar uma resposta pode fazer com que a sua pergunta receba menos respostas, por isso certifique-se que está satisfeito com a resposta.

Em relação a estes tópicos, pode ler [O que eu devo fazer se alguém responder minha pergunta?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) e [O que significa quando uma resposta é "aceita"?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)

3. Se não consegue obter uma resposta para a sua pergunta, [ofereça uma recompensa](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/bounty).

---

## OK a sua pergunta foi fechada e agora?

Um dos motivos que levam ao fechamento rápido de perguntas é que [**Nós não fazemos o seu código por você**](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5486/35970). Se você colocou uma pergunta deste género é provável que ela continuará fechada para todo o sempre.

Mas nada está perdido!

Se você fez uma pergunta deste género, o melhor que pode fazer é extrair a menor unidade de trabalho possível do seu problema.

Ou seja, em vez de perguntar "*Como posso fazer uma loja online com banco de dados SQL e Angular*", pergunte "*Como posso gravar os itens do carro de compras no banco de dados?*".

Você precisa obrigatoriamente mostrar trabalho, mostrando qual foi o seu esforço para cumprir essa funcionalidade. [De preferência com um Exemplo Mínimo, Completo e Verificável](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/6252/35970). Isto não garante que a sua pergunta será reaberta, mas aumentará as chances.

Se este não for o caso, não faz mal, porque todo o restante processo é o mesmo.

Você deverá analisar a pergunta criticamente. Veja os aspetos em falha e edite-a. Seja critico na sua edição. Espere 3 dias para reabertura. Tenha em conta os comentários, caso eles existam, e o material de ajuda provido nesta resposta.

Se a sua pergunta não foi reaberta e você pensa que deveria ter sido, você pode e deve colocar uma [pergunta aqui no Meta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) para esclarecer os motivos que levaram ao fechamento.
Conforme descrito em [Quantas possibilidade eu tenho de recuperar e melhorar a qualidade de minhas perguntas ja passadas](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7002)