# Minhas perguntas são fechadas rapidamente! É normal isso?

Tags: debate, destaque, fechamento

Confesso que estou ficando decepcionado em usar o Stack, de um tempo pra cá muitas das minhas perguntas estão ficando em analise com alguma ressalva então eu acabo excluindo porque não consigo entender o porque, eu não estou pedindo códigos prontos e nem uma solução fácil pra meu problema, simplesmente estou colocando o trecho do código que estou tendo dificuldade ou pedindo uma sugestão melhor para um problema.

Sei que ninguém aqui tem obrigação em responder pergunta alguma e agradeço de coração a disposição de todos aqueles com soluções ou criticas as minhas perguntas pois das duas formas nos faz pensar de outra maneira, o que acaba nos dando uma nova perspectiva e resolvendo a questão.

Mas ter a pergunta barrada em poucos segundos após a postagem, acho estranho, parece que a pessoa nem parou pra pensar qual a dificuldade que você esta tendo.

Tenho excluído as perguntas porque não consigo ver uma forma mais clara de coloca-la e não quero tumultuar o Stack com códigos e mais códigos desnecessários.

Não coloquei os links das perguntas barradas porque já as excluí.

Comment: Se as perguntas foram excluídas, vc pode colocar um screenshot (pelo seu perfil, *se não me engano* vc ainda pode acessá-las), ou transcrever o texto das mesmas. É que sem ver como estão as perguntas, fica difícil qualquer discussão sobre as mesmas... Lembrando que usuários com mais de 10000 pontos [podem ver perguntas deletadas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools), então pode colocar o link também, que algum destes usuários pode providenciar o screenshot se for o caso

Comment: Mais fácil seria simplesmente seguir as orientações dadas em vez de ficar fazendo seguidas perguntas de suporte e removendo. No último caso, por exemplo, simplesmente foi pedido um MCVE para podermos ajudar, coisa que você faria com duas ou três linhas de código a mais (e provavelmente fazendo isso acharia o problema por conta própria, se não achasse a comunidade provavelmente resolveria rapidamente), mas você simplesmente removeu a questão, optando pelo caminho mais complicado. Gastou mais tempo escrevendo este post aqui do que gastaria pra ter uma boa resposta no post original.

Comment: Importante notar que o SOpt não é um site de suporte e nem de ajuda. O que dá pra sugerir no seu caso, apesar de sua conta já ter 3 anos, é revisar o básico: [escopo do site](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [ask], [Manual de como NÃO fazer perguntas](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5483/70), [O que é o problema XY](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/499/70). Outro lugar legal para você discutir ou aprimorar a participação é o [chat da rede](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11910/estouro-de-pilha), onde pode conversar com colegas e conseguir ajuda para elaborar os posts.

Comment: Marcelo e a médio prazo, apagar perguntas, pode fazer que seja bloqueado de perguntar pelo sistema.

Comment: Hum, Jorge B achei que excluindo estava ajudando a não poluir o Stack, obrigado pela informação.

Comment: Toda vez que uma pergunta é fechada aparece um quadro amarelo logo abaixo da pergunta dizendo o motivo do fechamento, junto com links que auxiliam com informações mais detalhadas do porquê foi fechada e como você pode melhorar.  Cito, por exemplo, [esta pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/355944/5878), que foi fechada como "problema não pode ser reproduzido" e possui um link para "criação de um exemplo Mínimo, Completo e Verificável". Ao invés de excluir, você poderia focar seus esforços em elaborar o exemplo que reproduza o erro, tornando sua pergunta clara e suficiente para ser reaberta

Comment: Relacionada: [A minha pergunta foi fechada e agora?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7470/5878) | Se muitas das suas perguntas foram fechadas, talvez precise ler [Manual de como NÃO fazer perguntas](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5483/5878)

Comment: Quanto ao fechamento, é importante que ocorra o quanto antes se falta informação na pergunta, evitando respostas-chute que não contribuem com o autor e o site. Tem que lembrar que fechamento raramente é permanente aqui, exceto por problemas de escopo ou abandono. Se a pergunta foi fechada, geralmente tem motivo. Mais ainda se fechada por moderador, pois nestes casos é por ter algum problema ou necessidade de revisão realmente perceptível. Como disse o colega Anderson, no quadro amarelo tem uma explicação do que deve ser feito para reabrir, e eu costumo deixar orientações nos comentários.

Comment: Bacco, honestamente não estou te entendendo, (não leve isso como pessoal ok?)
Nos últimos meses você tem colocado ressalvas e sugestão de fechamento nas minhas perguntas de um modo progressivo, eu não mudei meu jeito de colocar perguntas nesses 3 anos que estou no stack, pode ser impressão minha, mas me parece que você le minhas perguntas de forma superficial e já coloca para fechar por isso eu excluo (achando que estava ajudando). Vou rever meu modo de postar as perguntas... agradeço sua ajuda.

Comment: @Marcelo não leio superficial não, li várias vezes, não encontrei o erro e pedi um MCVE pra poder responder com certeza e sem chutes. Não se ache um floco de neve especial para que eu tenha alguma predileção por fechar coisa sua, eu realmente avalio o conteúdo. Cheguei a pensar que fosse a vírgula no lugar do ponto (ponto em um campo, virgula no outro), mas realmente sem os dados concretos do MCVE seria chute dizer. E não se preocupe, pq apesar de eventualmente acabarmos lembrando dos usuários pelas ocorrências, não há nada pessoal no modo que a coisa é conduzida (ao menos, não da minha parte)

Comment: Sobre apagar a questão, complica, pois impede de outros ajudarem. Tem que lembrar que, apesar de fechada, os comentários continuariam abertos até para que alguém pudesse ver coisas que eu não vi, e até votar para reabrir em caso de enganos da minha parte ou de outro moderador. Pode ocorrer, somos pessoas. Lembrando ainda que está em tempo de restaurar e complementar.

Comment: Ok @Bacco, como eu disse foi minha impressão e sei que não existe nada pessoal, achei que tivesse feito algo de errado nas minhas perguntas e por isso estava em alguma lista para essas restrições, vou revisar melhor minhas perguntas antes de postar.

Comment: @Marcelo você lê as suas perguntas depois que você escreve? Só esta aqui no meta já posso dizer que tem problemas (não que precise ser fechada), mas o texto é confuso e tem coisas que não fazem sentido aqui. Me parece que o seu normal é colocar as coisas sem se preocupar se as pessoas vão entender, se o conteúdo está compreensível e faz sentido. E se não consegue perceber que tem problemas, é só um indicador que o problema é mais sério ligados à comunicação geral. O site é sobre programação, não espera-se que a pessoa saiba tudo disto, mas que consiga se comunicar adequadamente.

Comment: O fato de não dar exemplos nem podemos dizer se você está certo em alguma em específico, nem podemos dizer algo sobre alguma que você errou para mostrar onde está o problema. Entendeu como você tende a criar problemas e nem percebe isso? Pode haver erros, mas tudo indica que na maioria ou todos os casos é algo com você que complica a situação. Se puder nos ajudar um pouco mais poderemos ajudá-lo. Caso contrário isto aqui ficará apenas como um *rant* e nenhuma solução será dada, assim como não são dadas para suas perguntas.

Comment: @Marcelo um truque é ler a sua pergunta e pensar, se eu não soubesse do que estou a falar, perceberia este problema? Eu sei que por vezes não é simples fazer isso, mas tente ler sempre como se não soubesse nada do problema, para ver se os outros vão entender o que você está a perguntar.

Comment: Note como está todo mundo tentando te ajudar. Você está tentando se ajudar? De verdade? Será que depois de tanto tempo no site, de ter tanta ajuda não era hora de entender um pouco mais como o site funciona? Da necessidade das pessoas que vão te ajudar para poder ajudá-lo melhor? Será que você está realmente fazendo todo o esforço necessário para tornar suas perguntas boas? Só posso ficar no "será?" porque não tenho casos concretos pra analisar.

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/355944/101 Esta por exemplo (algumas pessoas podem ver) está confusa, ninguém sabe como pode testar isso e ver onde o erro ocorre, falta informação, é só um trecho de código que não dá para analisar o contexto, uma monte de informação solta que não ajudam. E pior tem um erro grave de programação que é falado aqui no site o tempo todo, e que é quase certo que já foi falado para você. O fato de não procurar informações, não procurar evoluir, e ainda hoje cometer erros básicos indica muita coisa. Me parece que precisa mudar a atitude para obter melhores resultados.

Comment: @Maniero, sim estou entendendo que querem me ajudar, é que as restrições começaram de uma forma progressiva (foi impressão), talvez na correria eu não tenha me dado conta de que minhas perguntas faltasse informação, o que me prendeu foi o fato delas ter a sugestão de fechamento, isso ao que me parecia era pra perguntas sem a ver com a programação e não por falta de algum detalhe que pudesse melhorar a pergunta, mas com essa discussão percebi que preciso tirar o pé do acelerador e melhorar no stack, agradeço mesmo a ajuda de vocês, e espero não estar causando problemas.

Comment: @Marcelo depende do nível da falta de informação. Cada motivo tem um uso. De qualquer forma se o fechamento tem motivo errado, está bem fechado, ainda que possa indicar mal o que fazer. No caso da pergunta que citei acima, tem um comentário com mais informações do que fazer.

Comment: Sim @Maniero, o que quero dizer é que junto com a dica do que eu poderia melhorar veio também a solicitação de fechamento, por isso os ??? na minha cabeça, na minha visão o fechamento deveria vir a perguntas "NADA" a ver com programação o que não me parece meu caso, ou perguntas com intuito de receber uma resposta fácil o que juro, não é meu caso, mas compreendo que não é fácil "adivinhar" o que o outro programador esta querendo :), Eu sugiro que antes de pedir o fechamento façam a sugestão, e depois de uns minutos sem resposta façam o fechamento se for o caso.

Comment: O fechamento é justamente para alertar o usuário de que há coisas em não conformidade. O mesmo deve ser feito rápido, os moderadores, ao meu ver, estão corretos. Cabe ao usuário seguir as recomendações ou vim questionar no meta, caso discorde do fechamento.

Comment: @Marcelo existem vários motivos e todos com descrição não existe só o fechamento que não é sobre programação. Novamente depende do caso, o que eu mostrei o motivo não é porque não programação ou quer um jeito fácil, é que ela não tem informação que permita reproduzi-lo, o que dá para pensar se não seria o caso de fechar como não clara, mas fechar era adequado. Depois de fechar dá para reabrir se não removê-la. Se não fechar, alguém tenta dar uma resposta só pra ganhar pontos ou por não entender o SOpt, e aí fica poluído com respostas que não servem porque a pergunta era ruim.

Comment: Entendi @Maniero, é que eu já vi varias perguntas onde alguns sugeriam o autor colocar mais detalhes (sem fechar) inclusive comigo isso já aconteceu, desculpe ser redundante, é que ultimamente as perguntas me parecem que tem passado por uma analise mais criteriosa, mas é impressão minha, essa discussão no Meta me clareou algumas coisas... eu estava vendo o a sugestão de fechamento como um monstro.

Comment: O fato de algo ocorrer não significa que deva ocorrer sempre. Depende de uma série de questões, inclusive da pessoa. O fato de algo não ser fechado nunca é justificativa para não fechar outras coisas, até porque pode ter sido um erro não fechar ali. Fechar é só uma indicação que tem problemas para responder adequadamente e algo precisa ser feito para ficar bom. Remover é um monstro que não permite solução :)

Comment: Eu já respondi a uma pergunta semelhante [Votos para fechar perguntas](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2673/votos-para-fechar-perguntas), em resumo perguntas Pendentes (ou Suspensas) e Fechadas não são perguntas Banidas e nem Deletadas, são perguntas que podem ser editadas e reabertas se necessário, em outras palavras, Fechar e Suspender não são coisas ruins. Deve-se ler com atenção aos comentários (se houver) e a tal caixa amarela abaixo da pergunta, fechamento nunca são arbitrários (não significa que não possam ser equívocos) e quem vota para fechar geralmente tentou sim ler.

Comment: Eu tive um problema, com uma pergunta a qual não era totalmente relacionada a código, e tive a pergunta marcada como pendente, isso me desanimou um bocado a fazer perguntas aqui, porque uma comunidade enorme como essa sempre tem alguém disposto a ajudar.

Comment: @Bulfaitelo exatamente, marcar como pendente **é ajudar** - é a forma correta de ajudar, afinal esta é a ferramenta que o stackoverflow oferece para que possamos solicitar mais informações a quem perguntou, sem poluir a pergunta com respostas desinformadas. Se alguém marcou sua pergunta como pendente, está te ajudando e não negando ajuda. Está te pendindo para consertar a pergunta para que ela possa ser respondida!

Comment: @nosklo justo, eu entendo, mas o motivo da da minha pergunta ser marcada como [pendente] não foi a falta de informação e sim o assunto da mesma, se não me engano era um problema com o mikrotik.

Comment: @Bulfaitelo aí já é outra discussão, se foi marcada como pendente **indevidamente**, você pode abrir outro questionamento aqui no meta e indicar um link para a pergunta, podemos reabrí-la

Comment: @nosklo eu devia ter comentando antes de excluir a pergunta, mas na caso aconteça esse mesmo caso, eu vou postar aqui, eu por sorte já resolvi o problema com meu mikrotik

Comment: Existem várias perguntas que eu entro, entendo o que a pessoa precisa, mas quando vou responder não consigo por estar em análise....

Comment: Verdade, mais chato ainda quando alguém negativa sua pergunta e não deixa nenhum comentário que indique o porque...

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Primeiro, é importante entender: **fechamento é reversível**.

- [A minha pergunta foi fechada. E agora?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7470/5878)

O fechamento da pergunta não é um decreto de que ela não é bem-vinda no site, embora  a grande maioria acha que sim. Se ela foi fechada, tente entender o motivo. Há vários requisitos mínimos de qualidade que a pergunta precisa satisfazer para ser mantida aqui - e [nossos requisitos são muito mais exigentes que outras comunidades Stack Overflow](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1/5878), como o inglês, por exemplo - muitos também reclamam disso; "*ah, mas no SOen eles não fecharam a pergunta*".

Sempre é possível também que a pergunta tenha sido fechada erroneamente. A comunidade é passível de erro. Se discorda do fechamento, existe o botão "reabrir" que reverterá o fechamento (ao obter alguns votos, assim como para fechar).

Se acha que pode ser um caso mais sério, que o erro foi grave, o Meta existe para isso, assim como se a pergunta foi fechada e você não entendeu como melhorar. Venha ao Meta e tire suas dúvidas; isso com certeza irá melhorar sua participação no site. Inclusive você fez certo ao perguntar isso aqui, só talvez demorou demais, deveria ter feito isso logo na primeira pergunta que ficou em dúvida. Excluir dificilmente é a melhor opção - e poderá ser penalizado por isso.

Como você excluiu as perguntas em questão, não há como dizer nada mais pontual - quem sabe a moderação o faça, se você permitir expor as perguntas que foram excluídas.

Todo fechamento é sinalizado através de um quadro azul (era amarelo antes):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Neste quadro, como pode ver, estão informações como:

- **Motivo do fechamento**, o que te permite saber porque sua pergunta foi fechada;
- **Detalhes do que fazer**, um texto que explica com mais detalhes e, principalmente, links que te levam a outras páginas que te auxiliarão a melhorar a pergunta e buscar reabri-la;
- **Lista de quem fechou**, o que te permite questionar o motivo em caso de dúvidas. A votação é transparente, você sempre conseguirá ver quem votou;

Neste [caso em particular](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/355944/erro-na-convers%C3%A3o-abs-php), podemos ver que a pergunta foi fechada porque o problema não podia ser reproduzido. Com as informações que apresentou, não tínhamos como reproduzir o erro no nosso ambiente e, assim, se torna impossível testarmos e apresentarmos possíveis soluções. Por isso, na descrição do fechamento há o link de como fazer um [exemplo mínimo, completo e verificável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Se o fizesse, provavelmente a pergunta seria reaberta.

Sua pergunta foi fechada? Não fique em dúvida! Leia os links que foram apresentados e, se ainda não achou suficiente, venha até ao Meta ou acesse nosso [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11910/estouro-de-pilha), lá também quase sempre há alguém online que pode lhe ajudar a entender melhor a situação.