# No momento há 800 traduções aguardando aprovação. Há um motivo?

Tags: bug, tradução

Boa tarde!

Há centenas de mensagens aguardando aprovação no https://pt.traducir.win. Nesse momento, temos 800 delas.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Tem alguém olhando para essas filas de aprovação ou há algum motivo para não terem sido aprovadas?

Comment: Somente moderadores controlam e aprovam essas filas?

Comment: Já verifiquei. [Pelo visto](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2705/mil-tradutores-s%c3%a3o-melhores-que-um?rq=1) somente moderadores, se este link estiver correto: _"Hoje temos 3 revisores: eu, o bfavaretto e o utluiz (nossos moderadores)."_

Comment: @CmteCardeal Ou seja, só sobrei eu, já que Gabe e utluiz não são mais moderadores. Vou responder e explicar por que está assim.

Comment: @bfavaretto sim, só estava tirando dúvidas e até estranhei porque não sabia que os outros eram ex-moderadores, mas depois vi que esse link já tem um tempo.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Atualmente, eu sou o único moderador que pode aprovar traduções – aliás, alguém mais se habilita? Por diversos motivos ando mais afastado do site, e honestamente até esqueci que essa ferramenta existia. Vou voltar lá e aprovar o máximo possível, e dou notícias novamente aqui.

Comment: Se ficou só você para aprovar, fica complicado mesmo. Na lista de usuários (https://pt.traducir.win/users) aparece uma dúzia de outros usuários (alguns ativos no site) com permissão de "Reviewer" (a mesma que a sua), eles também não podem aprovar? De qualquer forma, me habilito.

Comment: De usuários do SOpt que ainda vejo,  só tem 3 e um _Trusted User_. Pra analisar tudo isso, mesmo se tivesse 10, ainda seria pouco. Pelo fato de limitar a moderadores, fica dificil mesmo...

Comment: Eu não me importaria de ajudar com isso quando puder. Algo como todo dia não sei, mas algo como uma vez por semana, acho que seria viável para mim. Posso ajudar. :)

Comment: @bfavaretto, vi que me colocou como Trusted User, obrigado! Vou ajudar nas aprovações também. Notei que, ainda assim, precisará de alguém depois para aprovar na revisão (última coluna) o que já foi aprovado como sugestão pelo Trusted User. Ou seja, precisará ainda de um usuário "Reviewer" para a tradução de fato ser aceita. Não sei se era a sua intenção original, então fica a informação. Vi também que já aprovou centenas delas, valeu!

Comment: Me habilito. 