# O robot do site "became more participative", tem como torná-lo mais participativo?

Tags: bug, status-pronto, tradução, internacionalização

Recentemente pude verificar que o robot do site, [usuário Comunidade](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/-1/comunidade), está mais participativo.
Até o momento em que escrevo pude perceber que foram feitos oito comentários de orientação destinados tanto a Autores de Perguntas como Autores de Respostas.

Veja a [lista dos comentários feitos pelo robot do site](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/-1/comunidade?tab=activity):
[image: Imagem da lista de comentários feitos pelo robot do site]

O Problema não é a qualidade dos comentários mas o fato desses comentários estarem em língua inglesa.

Minha pergunta é:

**Tem como fazer o robot do site comentar estritamente em língua portuguesa?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Está feito. Os comentários do usuário Comunidade estão traduzidos:

[image: Comentários de feedback para respostas em português]

[![image: Comentários de feedback para perguntas em português]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kI8X0.png)

---

O que o @Maniero disse está correto, mas vou complementar.

Esta atualização veio hoje (26/08/2021) com as novas filas de análise, você pode ver o anúncio no [Meta StackExchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/369013/818993). Segue o trecho relevante (ênfase minha):

> *Reviewers are encouraged to leave comments for the post-author, but now they can also choose from a few options of canned feedback **which will appear as a comment from the Community account**.*

As traduções das frases podem ser feitas no [Traducir](http://pt.traducir.win), e eu sugiro que as marque como urgentes. Eu já havia sugerido algumas traduções, principalmente sobre as filas de análise, que tem muitas coisas em inglês, mas faltam aprovações para as traduções. É por isso que tem frases urgentes que não são da atualização de hoje.

Quero ressaltar que mesmo essas frases terem sido lançadas hoje, algumas já foram modificadas (em inglês). Caso já estivessem traduzidas, voltariam para o inglês da nova frase - não tenho certeza disso, mas é o que percebo acontecendo nas atualizações.

Há também um *feature request* para possibilitar que cada site crie novas possíveis mensagens, [veja aqui](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/369052/818993), mas isso já é [mais trabalhoso](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/369013/review-queue-workflows-final-release#comment1231232_369018) e deve levar um tempo, caso venha a ser implementado de fato.

De todo modo, a tradução não é um trabalho complexo, e o [Google Tradutor](http://translate.google.com/translate) pode ajudar como ferramenta auxiliar. Basta apenas ficar atento caso algo volte a ficar em inglês. Apesar de existirem mais de 4.000 frases sem tradução, algumas são do *Teams*, outras são de *Collectives* e outros produtos que não existem no SOpt, então não precisam ser traduzidas.

Answer (score 4):

Isso não é bem um bot. Isso é sempre resultado de uma sinalização de um humano, ele apenas posta algo enlatado.

O que é postado pode ser traduzido sempre, basta ter interessados em fazê-lo e moderadores para aprovar. Pode ver mais em [No momento há 800 traduções aguardando aprovação. Há um motivo?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8597/101). Então a sugestão é que as pessoas façam a tradução lá do Traducir.